# Boot from USB on a Macbook

Tags: live-usb, mac

How do I boot from USB on a Mac? Mac OS X crashed on that PC and I want to make the owner switch to Ubuntu.

Comment: It's worth noting that for whatever reason, Apple has decided to be insane and not allow booting from USB in the vast majority of cases. Essentially the drive needs to have OS X installed on it, which is just silly.

Comment: Same solution for similar question just check 
[boot from USB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key/313443#313443)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

solution on the apple support site: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1948

the gist of the answer is press the option key during boot and select the device....some devices have issues.  there are troubleshooting steps at the website linked above

Answer (score 1):

Just see the link below.. this might tell you 
Choose your device carefully
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook

Answer (score -1):

A single-filesystem image like the Ubuntu *amd64+mac* ISO or Debian installer ISOs on a USB stick will work fine to boot MacBooks from the boot selector that appears when you press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key during startup.