# What is different about the Mac ISO image?

Tags: macbook, iso

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/release/

At that location there is an ISO image which is described as "This image is adjusted to work properly on Mac systems."

What specific problems on the Mac does this image address that the standard images don't? I ask because I need to know which ISO to recommend to Apple Mac users.

Comment: Without actually having tried it: the older alt-install releases were text-mode (ncurses). Macs don't have those legacy text modes - have you ever seen text mode on old PPC Macs? It's pretty awful.

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Comment: Have you managed to install Ubuntu so that it boot from **UEFI** and not using BIOS emulation?

Comment: @gentmatt Yes, but I wouldn't recommend it. The nvidia binary video driver doesn't work with EFI mode, so you're limited to nouveau which is okay, but also limited. I ended up getting rid of the Mac for this and other reasons and switched to a Thinkpad which "Just Works" (TM).

Comment: @popey Actually, I want to use EFI boot in order to make use of the integrated graphics ;). The battery life with dedicated graphics only is horrible.... But yes, I'm also thinking of getting a proper computer to run Ubuntu. Doing this on a Mac just doesn't seem very reasonable at the moment. If you can't make *good* use of the expensive hardware, you'd better leave it.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

In Ubuntu 10.10, we changed the normal `amd64` CD images to dual-boot on either BIOS or UEFI systems (UEFI, "Unified Extensible Firmware Interface", is a different kind of firmware found on many newer systems).  This was done using a technique known as a "multi-catalog" CD - it contains two boot images, and the specification says that the firmware is supposed to pick the one it can best use.

Unfortunately, even though Macs use a variant of EFI (an earlier version of what's now called UEFI), they apparently can't cope with multi-catalog CDs, and simply [refuse to boot them](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/633983).  This left us in rather a quandary: we needed to support UEFI systems, but we didn't want to drop support for Macs either.  I therefore created the `amd64+mac` CD images, which are exactly the same as the `amd64` images except that they only support BIOS booting.  Macs are happy to boot these in their BIOS emulation mode.

(In fact, the name `amd64+mac` is a slight misnomer, because it later turned out that some systems other than Macs suffer from a similar problem - but I felt that a more technically accurate naming such as `amd64+nouefi` would be more likely to confuse than enlighten.)

While I would love to return to shipping just `amd64` images rather than both `amd64` and `amd64+mac`, at the moment there is no prospect of reunifying them unless somebody figures out how to make a multi-catalog CD image that Macs can boot.  If you're an expert on this, please do contact me by e-mail.

Comment: Is the BIOS emulation mode the reason for why it takes relatively longer to boot Ubuntu on a Mac? First rEFIt and then Grub2. After that there is always a **"pause" with a black screen**. Then comes the boot splash which is significantly faster than this strange pause with the black screen. **Is there an update on using UEFI boot on Macs** in order to avoid this?

Comment: If you want to go ahead and use UEFI boot, feel free to try the normal amd64 images and see if they work on your system.

Comment: If the problem with *multi-catalog CDs* is that you can't have both methods on the same CD why did you choose BIOS over EFI?

Comment: On the wild goose chase that i have been put on by the experts here at Ask Ubuntu and at Launchpad found your concise answer more than helpful in the process of elimination on getting to install Ubuntu using EFI mode on a 2011 EFI 2.1 machine (which is not a mac)

Comment: Is there amd64+mac for 16.04.1?

Comment: P.S. I guess there is no, but it hard to create one?

Comment: No, it was dropped in 2014, IIRC because only a small range of machines needed it and modern ones were just fine with the normal amd64 image, and it was a significant testing burden around release time.

Answer (score 14):

Appears to be very little between them, mostly the beginnings of EFI booting:

```
$ diff --context=0 ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64*list
*** ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64+mac.list 2011-04-27 18:06:42.000000000 +0100
--- ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.list 2011-04-27 18:05:44.000000000 +0100
***************
*** 4 ****
--- 5 ----
+ /usb-creator.exe
***************
*** 134,135 ****
- /isolinux/grub/font.pf2
- /isolinux/grub/grub.cfg
--- 134 ----
***************
*** 144 ****
--- 144 ----
+ /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
```

I've not personally had much luck with the uefi booting, so I'd probably recommend users stick to the regular amd64 releases until uefi is required.  (on most models, the regular disks work fine via bootcamp's bios emulation layer)

Answer (score 6):

Coming from someone who installs Ubuntu on a lot of Macs. There were supposedly some difficulties encountered by some of the people who tried to run Maverick LiveCD's on Mac computers. The EFI loader wasn't friendly with it, so the Natty version with Mac support is meant to interact better with the EFI (Mac version of a BIOS) to solve these problems. Aside from that, there isn't a signifigant difference.

I would advise trying the regular downloads first (if you can spare the bandwidth) because I find them to work great on the Macs that I have used them on. If you encounter problems trying to load up the LiveCD's, then the Mac support version is likely what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the reason for these +mac CDs is that Macs use [EFI](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface), whereas most other computers are using a regular BIOS interface (hardware *interface*, not GUI). For MAC then, a different CD is needed in order to allow the system to boot.

This is also why there is bootcamp - apart from driver support; windows (at least in older versions I AFAIK) does not use EFI.

Answer (score 0):

The question is discussed by Matt Gadient [here](https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/).
This page also contains images of few distributions which work for mac.
It also contains a short [code](https://mattgadient.com/dl/linux-iso-program/isomacprog.c.txt) that suppose to convert an iso image into its +mac version. Works perfectly.

Comment: Links to answers off-site can rot away over time.  Could you perhaps supply more details in your answer?

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat Indeed, it is better to move code here, but I think one needs a permission from Matt Gadient.