# Do I need to use rEFIt if I want to install ubuntu on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: 12.04, mac, refit

I am considering getting the new MacBook Pro and dual-booting OS X and  Ubuntu. All the help pages I found say I need to use rEFIt but is that really necessary? Can't I just use the default OS choose thing Macs already have preinstalled, because rEFIt is just really ugly in comparison to that.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58813/install-ubuntu-on-a-macbook-pro-using-efi-instead-of-refit-or-similar

Answer (score 0):

I have an Ubuntu / Mac OS X dual boot system, but never installed REFIT. I do not know why people make such a fuss of this.

I just press the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and then I can choose OS X or Ubuntu.

Comment: your case is interesting, please could you indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) in order to know if your Ubuntu is using grub-efi, or BIOS-boot, or else.

Comment: Is this true for Mavericks as well?