# What is the difference between the AMD64 and AMD64+mac images?

Tags: live-cd, cd-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is different about the Mac ISO image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image)

I decided to download todays image for Precise, and I saw that there was an image called precise-desktop-amd64.iso and one called precise-desktop-amd64+mac.iso. What is the difference between them?

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Comment: That's the first time I've voted to close my own question. :) But I think it can act as a good signpost, so I decided not to delete it. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: much appreciated. I used the site search, nothing came up. Started writing a question and yours popped up. Thanks!