# Why are there no amd64+mac images for precise beta 1?

Tags: 64-bit, 12.04, mac, aspire-one

When I installed oneiric on my Acer Aspire AO722-0828, I needed to use the `amd64+mac` images.

I'd like to try precise now, but there are no beta 1 `amd64+mac` images—only `amd64`; I've looked in both http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ and http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/beta-1/.

Is the `amd64+mac` issue resolved?  Based on [this explanation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image), I'd expect it's impossible to "resolve" it, but the lack of beta images makes me wonder.

Comment: I dont know the real reason - but these images are in the daily build area - so I would surmise the issue has not been resolved... http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`amd64+mac` images have appeared for beta 2.

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/beta-2/