# How to install Ubuntu 12.04 to EEE PC 1225B?

Tags: installation, 12.04, eeepc

How to install Ubuntu 12.04 to EEE PC 1225B?

I tried to install from USB Flash and USB CD -
Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Debian, Fedora, Mint.
Installation is going well, but after installing the OS will not boot.

[Hardware Specs](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1225B/)

Comment: Could you see any screen with some error messages like grub-rescue_ ? Please explain your post with all the details you can collect from the system feedback.

Comment: Oleg. I've added the specs to the question. Please check the link to verify they are correct.

Answer (score 2):

My 1225B was delivered with win7 preinstalled. Windows 7 did not boot via UEFI so to be able to install ubuntu side-by-side with the existing os I forced ubuntu into installing in legacy (non uefi) mode. Grub seem to detect that the computer supports uefi but does not understand why the efi partition is missing. (because uefi it is not used)

The easiest way to install without using uefi is to remove the efi folder from the installation medium. It works on both ubuntu and windows 7.

Comment: On 64-bit systems, if you want to prevent the installation medium from being UEFI-bootable (for systems where UEFI is broken, since if it really doesn't have it, it should just fallback to normal BIOS booting), you can also [use the "Mac" images](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image/40480#40480).

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Sardu, you can use the tool that comes with ubuntu to create your boot usb. However, the Ubuntu version that creates this boot usb must be equal or probably greater than the usb version you are trying to create.

I tried creating a boot usb with  Ubuntu 10.10  from a 12.04 iso, got the same error.

After doing the same process with 12.04 got a successful boot usb.

Comment: Helpful answer, thanks. Could you mention the name of the tool for the convenience of those referring to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make USB bootable with a software called sardu. And then try to reinstall Ubuntu or whatever you want. Select the hard driver where you want to install the OS. And make it primary bootable through BIOS!

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
To create a bootable USB flash, I used
unetbootin-www.acerfans.ru.exe and 
ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Excellent have been booted from bootable USB flash and installed on the HDD,
but when rebooting can not boot from HDD

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on the same hardware. When I started the machine and went to the boot selector, there were two options for my LiveUSB: SanDisk, and UEFI:SanDisk (Obviuosly I was using a SanDisk USB). I kept selecting UEFI:SanDisk and the install would always have problems, but after I noticed the other choice on the boot selector, I tried it and the install worked without problems. Hope that helps.