# Why doesn't the Ubuntu ISO burned to a CD or copied to a USB work on my Mac?

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, macbook

I just installed a new hard drive and for the life of me, I cannot get the .iso file on my USB stick or burned CD to begin the installation process.

I keep getting a picture of a folder with a question mark on it....

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're burning/writing it correctly according to these instructions...

- [How to burn a DVD on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-mac-osx)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

...the problem might be that you're using the wrong ISO image.

- [What is different about the Mac ISO image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image/40480#40480)

So, if you're trying to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu on a Mac, you should use the special ISO image for that purpose. It is called the **64-bit Mac (AMD64) desktop CD**.

- For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, [you can get it here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/).
- For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, [you can get it here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/).
- For Ubuntu 11.10, [you can get it here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/11.10/release/).
- For Ubuntu 11.04, [you can get it here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/).

Answer (score 2):

- Just copying *the ISO file* to the USB, or burning the file to the CD **will not work**.

  - ISOs contain a CD image, and it's that *image* which needs to be burned to a CD or transferred to a USB.
- Please insert a blank CD and open Disk Utility to burn the ISO (the ISO will refuse to mount if you just double-click it)
- Or use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sf.net) to "burn" the image to a USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the entire ISO file downloaded. It should be 981MB. Twice I downloaded the iso from the site, but it wasn't the full file although there were no errors with the D/L or indications that it didn't complete.

Comment: It is better to ask the OP to check the [hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) than to rely simply upon the filesize.