# Installing Ubuntu Server 15.04 on Mac Mini with Ubuntu Desktop Installed

Tags: boot, usb, mac

I have a Mac Mini that I somehow (god knows how) managed to install Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 onto in the past. I want to reinstall Ubuntu Server 15.04 on to the Mac Mini but I can't get it to recognize my USB stick or DVDs.

**What I've done**

1. Created a USB stick from a Windows machine using LinuxLive USB Creator, plugged the USB stick in, got to the startup selector. The only listing is the internal HDD with the name "Windows"
2. Burned the image to a DVD, interested it into the Mac Mini, rebooted. I get to a screen that says "Select CD-ROM Option" and no options are listed
3. Burned the image to a CD. Same results as the DVD.

I assume I'm missing a step somewhere here. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing ubuntu onto mac mini](http://askubuntu.com/questions/301457/installing-ubuntu-onto-mac-mini)

Comment: or maybe also this would be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/515327/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-mac-mini

Comment: Post the name of the file you downloaded. Post the model or model identifier of your Mac Mini. if you have OS X installed, what version is it?

Comment: @DavidAnderson the file is: ubuntu-15.04-server-amd64.iso, model number: A1176. I no longer have OS X installed, it's running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: The A1176 came with many different processors. I was trying to determine if your processor is 64 bit. Do you know if your processor is a Core Solo, Core Duo or Core 2 Duo? Also the processor speed could help determine the Model Identifier.

Comment: Ah, it's a 32 bit processor. Didn't even think of that. It's a Core Solo T1400 (that's what Ubuntu says it is) at 1.83Ghz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Solo is a 32 bit processor. You need to download the file `ubuntu-15.04-server-i386.iso` and burn to a DVD. This would be the [32-bit PC (i386) server install image](http://mirror.pnl.gov/releases/vivid/). The file is 625 MB in size so a CD might work.

(Of course, by the time you read this post, you will have already figured this out.)

Comment: Thanks David! Can't believe I never thought to check that. Everything is 64 bit right? Haha