# Upgrading OLD model Mac Mini A1176 (32bit firmware) to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, mac, 32-bit, mac-mini

I'm looking for answers here. I've tried a number of options.

I have an A1176 mac, I'd like it to run the latest stable version of Ubuntu (Trusty Tahr) on account that it will only run Snow Leopard, which is getting slower by the hour and often does not have good software.  I'm looking to turn to Linux (Debian or Ubuntu) for continued functionality for the next 4-5 years (I'm hoping).  I'm NOT looking for a dual boot or virtual OS.

The Mac install iso will not work because it is 64 bit, and this mac has a 32 bit firmware.  Additionally, this ([Installing ubuntu onto mac mini](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301457/installing-ubuntu-onto-mac-mini)) guide did not work for the latest version of ubuntu.

Help?

Comment: Came here looking for a similar answer, but found this also: [Installing Ubuntu 16.04 Server on Mac Mini 2006](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242542/installing-ubuntu-16-04-server-on-mac-mini-2006)