# How do i find and boot from windows boot manager in Grub 2 after deleting Ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, efibootmgr

**Question:**
Is it possible to find, locate, or install the windows 10 boot manager through the grub 2 command line?
If so, what are those commands?

I cannot boot into windows of course and i can not enter ubuntu either. If the questions above are not possible, what are my options? I only want/need windows.

**Situation:**
I have a dual boot (windows 10 & Ubuntu) installation on my laptop HDD, and no longer wanted to keep ubuntu on my hdd. I wanted to erase all trace of ubuntu so that i could safely transfer data to an ssd.

So Naturally, as someone new to linux, i thought it made sense to simply delete the linux partition from Windows’ Disk Manager since windows was (pre)installed first. Then migrate the data over to the clean ssd.

**Problem:**
After deleting the linux partition and extending the c drive to take over unallocated space, I can no longer boot windows. As soon as i turn on my laptop, the GNU GRUB ver 2.04 shows up. In the command line it displays: “grub> ”
(It is Not grub rescue)

Typing “exit” simply brings me back to the same screen. The UEFI menu that i have doesnt have any option change the boot back to windows bootmgr. I dont have a windows installation disk, or any external windows backup device that was recommended. And I dont currently have but could make another ubuntu live usb, if necessary. But it would be cool if i could do this in grub

Neither the hdd nor the ssd can boot windows nor ubuntu. But both devices bring up the GRUB> command line. I now know that data migration moves everything except the boot manager itself. Ive also learned that installing ubuntu gave the booting reigns to ubuntu and took that control away from windows. Which is why uninstalling ubuntu from windows caused this issue..

So my question is, since ubuntu is gone, is windows boot manager also erased? Or is it possible to locate it through GRUB?

Comment: Thanks that was a long page full of helpful answers regarding uninstalling linux properly and also regarding being able to boot again-whether though a live Ubuntu usb, or a Windows recovery cd/dvd. I did hope that i could do this through the GRUB2 command line, but i think i will go make a live ubuntu usb then take the steps to eventually recover the windows OS

Comment: My question was about whether i could navigate Linux’s GRUB2 to locate the windows boot manager or whether it still exists. Seeing your linked answer, i will assume using a ubuntu or even a windows live cd is the only avenue now to boot an operating system again.

Comment: It sounds like you have an old BIOS/MBR configuration. Then only one boot loader can be in MBR. And grub in MBR has most of its code in the Linux partition including the options to boot other installs. The amount of code in MBR is tiny. You need your Windows repair/recovery flash drive to restore Windows boot loader or can use Linux to install a Windows "like" boot loader. If UEFI, it will show a Windows entry & then only have to change that to default. Best to use newer UEFI installs if newer hardware.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair can install syslinux BIOS bootloader.

Comment: Thanks for sending that boot-repair link/tip! Thats very helpful for me working with ubuntu/linux in the future. I dont think i have bios or mbr configuration on my laptop. I upgraded a while back and have UEFI mode activated but i think it is an old version? I think its an old UEFI because i dont have an option to pick a default boot loader from within it. And The listed drives in GRUB shown with command <ls -l > all are GPT. when things were working normally, the grub OS menu let me choose between Ubuntu, Ubuntu recovery, and Windows boot manager. That being said, ill make a ubuntu usb now

Comment: I booted up a live usb of ubuntu but boot-repair wasnt found. But after running sudo apt update, ubuntu had to restart. After my computer restarted, windows automatically fired right up with no issue!? I took the usb out and restarted again and windows booted without me having to do anything. The GRUB OS menu selection doesnt even show up. Im thinking the software installations and updates fixed or added something that was missing with my boot loaders

Comment: If you boot with an Ubuntu Full install USB and run `sudo update-grub`, Windows will be added to the USB's boot menu. Then you can boot windows from the USB. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi

Answer (score -1):

This answer is for other linux beginners who have the same seemingly unanswered question.
According to the situation in this question, locating and booting through windows boot manager is not possible. Because the ubuntu partition was erased before configuring Windows boot manager to have priority over grub/ubuntu, windows boot manager was also erased along with ubuntu.

Windows boot manager will no longer be available unless a windows recovery cd is used; or another [linux] live usb is inserted to allow you to boot an OS again.

According to the bounds of this question, booting from either Windows or linux live device will set you up to be able to follow the steps to remove Ubuntu properly and boot windows again. This is because the Ubuntu OS contained the boot orders. This ownership also explains why after installing [linux] you have to go through [linux’s] GRUB OS menu in order to choose your OS.