# A persistent ubuntu instalation in a external hdd is any diferent from the same instalation in a pen drive?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd, persistence

I want to install ubuntu in a 1 Terabyte toshiba external hdd , to be like a normal bootable persistent internal hdd. But in the past i did a persistent instalation of lubuntu in a usb pen drive of 8 gb, and as result the pendrive would eventually crash as i did more and more system upgrades. So i learn it wasnt a good idea to use a pen drive as a persistent bootable hd.

So i'm afraid the external hdd would be like the pen drive, and eventually crush under a persistent instalation of ubuntu. Could that happen ?  Or the external hdd would be exactaly like a internal hdd ?

Comment: *"the external hdd would be like the pen drive"*. They have a different storage mechanism, so it won't be the same. *"Or the external hdd would be exactaly like a internal hdd?"*. It won't be the same in the sense that comunication with the computer's hardware is done by different ways: SATA for an internal HDD/SDD, and USB for the external, which has lower speed in comparison..

Comment: but apart from speed and internals of communication protocols, **logically** they should all look and work the same. The question is only whether your computer can boot from an external HDD. If your USB installation crashed because of no space on the USB drive, then the external HDD drive definitely has more space available, so it should not crash. If there was another reason to crash (eg. related to the fact that it's a persistent live installation and not a "regular" installation), then it may crash as well.

Comment: Some tools that create live installers use dd or dd under the hood. That erases the first 2+GB of a drive, in effect erasing drive as it overwrites partition table. Often better just to do a full install.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step

Comment: The problem is that with a Live install you fill the persistent file or partition, then the drive does not boot. Better to do a **Full install** to the external drive, same as to internal drive. A fast way to create a **Full install** to external drive is to flash a pre-built image file to it, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi