# I'm unable to install Kubuntu 20.04 on a flash drive

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, usb-installation

I am trying for quite some time to have a flash drive with kubuntu installed on it, so I can use it on whatever computer I am on, but for some reason, the installation process to install it to a internal HD won't work with the flash drive.

I have tried installing automatically by selecting "Use entire disk" but it gets stuck on "creating Ext4 file system for / ... 33%" or "on copying files 56%".

And when i try to install it by making the partitions myself, i never leave the "creating Ext4 file system for / ... 33%". Except when i have the partitions already made and just select the mounting point without formating, but then, i get stuck on the copying files message as described earlier.

I am really out of ideas by now. Is it something with ubuntu or kubuntu itself making me unable to install it to a USB drive? I don't mean the live version, i want to keep my data on it.

Comment: Have you tried another USB drive? Is it faulty?

Comment: It is brand new and it works for everything else, but i did not try it with another one, i don't own one with enough space. @popey

Comment: Here is a Full install method that is hard to mess up: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi But it is for Ubuntu only at present. You can always change the desktop.

Comment: I will try it, but I am starting to consider that the USB may be the problem. I will test it with a new one and edit the post with my findings. @C.S.Cameron