# How to install Ubuntu on new SSD on old computer

Tags: 20.04, live-usb, ssd

I have set up a bootable USB with the latest LTS release but the BIOS does not recognize it. It only sees the empty SSD. I have tried it on my laptop and it boots fine. I think it may be because the PC is very old but it did see USB last time when i installed version 18(bionic beaver). Can i install it when booted in the HDD somehow?

Comment: If your PC is very old, then it probably does have the DVD drive? Try installing from DVD. From my experience, I always suggest to boot from DVD whenever possible (and this refers to any OS, not only particularly to Ubuntu). Only if there's no DVD drive, try USB.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with BIOS-UEFI mode. Here is a method to flash a Full install of Ubuntu to SSD that will boot in either mode: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi