# I cannot boot into Windows, neither with Grub or Refind and neither in UEFI or Legacy modes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

So a little bit of backstory first: I originally ran a Ubuntu 18.04/Windows 8.1 Dual Boot setup and everything ran fine. But I was running into some problems regarding the space of my Ubuntu partition, so I decided to do a fresh installation of Lubuntu 20.04 to overwrite my old Ubuntu. All of the steps were successful and it installed correctly. However, after this I was unable to boot into Windows 8.1. Its filesystem was still present and I could mount it in Linux, however no matter what I did I could not get it to show up in Grub. After looking online some people recommended installation rEFInd but it wasn't finding Windows either.

Using the `boot-repair` utility, I got a message saying I had an installation of Windows in legacy mode(which I found out because I was booting in UEFI for my previous installation of Ubuntu and everything was fine). Trying to start my computer in Legacy mode just resulted in a black screen saying "No boot image found" or something similar .I booted a live USB and used `boot-repair` again,the details of which can be found [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YK7wC29Qyb/). After this I was able to boot my Lubuntu in Legacy mode but still no sign of Windows.

After this I tried using `boot-repair` again, `grup-update` and even defining a custom grub entry pointing to the partition where Windows was supposedly booting from. I tried all of these things in both Legacy and UEFI mode. I've tried just about everything I could find on the Internet but nothing worked.

My (admittedly uneducated) guess is that, while setting up the partitions during the Lubuntu install, I somehow messed up and erased/damaged something crucial to Windows booting. What I did during that step was, following the instructions, create a new root partition out of my old Linux partition and some unalocated space, as well as create an EFI System Partition(overwriting one pre-existing partition which I believed was the old Ubuntu's boot partition. If the fault is in the installation step, I'm almost sure it was due to this.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/X6Pwujdv) is the output of the output of the `bootinfoscript`utility and below is the output of `lsblk -f`:

```
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL    UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/chromium/1479
loop1  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/core/10823
loop2  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/core18/1988
loop3  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop4  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop5  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/postman/132
loop6  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/rustup/617
loop7  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/snapd/11036
sda
├─sda1 ntfs     Recovery 62107AA6107A80B9
├─sda2 vfat              4DF5-12AD
├─sda3
├─sda4 ntfs     Acer     8C787EE3787ECC08                       49,2G    88% /home/diogor/windows
├─sda5 ext4              3619ba7c-87d2-4f85-add7-e8890a226259   16,7G    55% /
└─sda6
sr0
```

Thanks in advance. If any further information is required I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: You still show the UEFI Windows partition on a gpt drive, but not any Windows UEFI boot files in the ESP - efi system partition. You also have a bios_grub partition where you must have installed in old BIOS Mode. Only use UEFI boot. Boot live installer in UEFI mode & reinstall grub in UEFI mode. Then boot Windows repair/recovery drive in UEFI mode an repair Windows.Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: If you have no luck soon you can make a Fill install USB that booth bot Legacy and UEFI mode: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi. You can then boot this (in both modes), and run `sudo update-grub` which should add Windows to it's boot menu. If Windows then boots you know where the problem is.

Comment: I believe you totally erased Windows booting from your EFI partition. There should be a Microsoft folder with a boot configuration file \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD. You'll have to rebuild it using a Windows 10 install image. Stick to UEFI boot and follow directions from [here](http://woshub.com/clone-windows-installation-to-new-hdd-ssd/). Only the second half of the post applies to your case. Once you're able to boot Windows, you'll have to reinstall grub from a live CD and update-grub.