# Help booting hard drive

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, uefi

Some time ago I made a kubuntu 16.04 live USB. I booted from this and installed kubuntu to a hard drive (flash) in the system. When the system booted I needed to select an option to boot the specific hard drive from the menu. After a couple of months I went to start the system again and this boot option is no longer there. I seem to remember it being off an "advanced options sub menu", something like "boot hda2".
If I boot the live system the hard disk is shown and I can see all of the files. I have backed up my work but I would still like to boot hard drive. I have spent hours looking for a solution including disk-repair but can't seem to get anything to work.

The disk in question comes up as disk /dev/sda, partition 1 is EFI and 2 is the main root disk with the boot directory containing all the kernel boot files.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/h3pMKX8nw3/ Here is the disk-repair link it seems there is an installation on sda2 and another on sda4. Really just need to boot sda2 and don't know what sda4 is.

Comment: You have two installs of 16.04. And the /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg refers to one that does not exist. You can run a full reinstall of grub using Boot-Repair's advanced options. Choose install either sda2 or sda4 which ever you want and full reinstall of grub.

Comment: Are you trying to boot the hard drive from the USB or from the hard drive's own grub? If from USB how did you make the USB, what program? And do you prefer booting from the USB?

Comment: I would love to be able to boot directly from the hard drive but I guess the BIOS does not recognize the UEFI partition. So I had been using the usb created with a kbuntu iso and Universal-USB-Installer. For some reason that no longer seems to have the option to boot the hard drive, so I have no way to boot it. Going to try the full install with boot-repair

Comment: @vmhb I boot one of my computers using a full install USB, I just had to boot it and update grub. Kind of a hassle though. Don't forget to backup your hard drive, good luck.

Comment: Had a go with the advance repair and still the boot device is not recognized by the BIOS and if I boot the live USB there is still no option to boot the hard drive http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DVkcQSW3Hb/

Comment: II have been playing around in grub command line. ls only seems to list the live USB as a device. The only ls that seems to work is ls (hd0,1) which it says is a 4GB FAT partition. I was hoping to find the SSD somewhere and try and manually instruct it to boot from that. Should I be able to see it here and is that my issue? Do I need a different grub?

Comment: Looking at the link provided regarding EOL, what I think I am trying to boot is 16.04.7 LTS.

Comment: @vmhb: if you have a blank 16GB or larger pendrive, install Full Ubuntu on it, (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi), Boot from it and run `sudo update-grub`. This should add the hard drive to it's boot menu, allowing you to boot the hard drive as before. you may be able to copy this menuentry to the hard drive's /boot/grub/grub.cfg on partition 2.

Answer (score 0):

### Booting Hard Drive from Universal USB Installer Boot Drive

Recent versions of **UUI** do not seem to have an option to boot the hard drive.

Following is how I modified a **Universal-USB-Installer-2.0.0.0** Lubuntu 16.04 install to use Syslinux to boot to the HDD in BIOS mode.

- Open `/uui/syslinux.cfg` in Notepad.

**syslinux.cfg**
[image]

- Directly after the first menu label add:

  ```
  # Boot from HDD
  LABEL Boot from Hard Drive
  MENU LABEL Boot from  Hard Disk
  KERNEL chain.c32
  APPEND hd1
  MENU DEFAULT
  ```
- Save and close Notepad.
- Copy `chain.c32` from the `isolinux` folder to the `uui` folder.

**The option to boot from Hard Disk should now be on the start menu.**

[image]

Some versions of UUI locate `syslinux` in the root folder, in that case copy `chain.c32` to the root folder.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help syslinux on the usb live disk looks like this

Comment: # This file was automatically populated by Universal USB Installer - http://www.pendrivelinux.com
prompt 0

LABEL append
CONFIG //syslinux.cfg
APPEND /

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to work this

Comment: I have tried to add the lines you suggested at different places but the menu presented does not change. I will try ans post a picture.

Comment: @vmhb: What version of Universal are you using? I have shown the full syslinux.cfg above

Comment: 1.9.8.8, Trying with same version as you.

Comment: Ok can get up the added boot hard disk option but when I attempt to use it I get "Cannot get disk parameters" then the "boot:" prompt.

Comment: @vmhb: When you get to the boot screen shown above press `Tab` to edit. It will say `chain.c32 hd1`. Try changing that to say `chain.c32 hd0` or ``chain.c32 hd2`, etc.

Comment: I did actually try 0 but now tried 0-5 and get the same error message. Really appreciate your suggestions, any more ideas? I did notice that when the machine boots it provides 2 options to boot from the usb stick. One is UEFI Part 0 OS Boot loader. This one is chosen by the BIOS as default and is not the boot menu we are changing. To get that to appear I have to select something marked USB Part 0 boot drive. If I remove the usb stick no boot device is found. I also tried recreating the usb stick and formatting it first. I though this was the menu in isolinux but appears to be different.

Comment: @vmhb: It would be nice to see what your HDD looks like in GParted. Lets try reinstalling GRUB. Booting from the USB, in Terminal run `sudo mount /dev/sdxy /mnt` where `sdx` is the HDD and `y` is the root partition number. Then run `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx` If HDD does not then boot without help from the USB, have a look at `sdxy/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to confirm that UUID's etc match what is shown in Disks

Comment: The command gives an warning. grub-install : warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS boot partition; embedding won't be possible. There is a /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg is that worth looking at? fdisk /dev/sda shows sda1 512M EFI, sda2 linux 55G, sda3 swap 4G, sda4 linux 20G, sda5 linux 4G.

Comment: Reboot USB and try `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`, then `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda`. If that doesn't work, copy the boot folder from the USB to the sda partition and try installing grub again

Comment: /dev/sda1 is EFI so when I mount it there is an EFI directory which contains the Boot and ubuntu directories. There is no /mnt/boot. So do I copy /boot (usb drive) to /mnt/boot which is the EFI partition? Copied the /boot and attempted grub-install. Still says there is no BIOS boot partition.

Comment: Create a 1MB partition. at the front of disk Use GParted to format it "unformatted" then flag it **bios_grub**. Confirm sda1 has **boot** and **esp** flags. try installing grub again to sda1.

Comment: Since creating the boot partition it seems now the root disk has moved to sdb2 and the EFI partition to sdb1. I have tried to run the grub-install command on sdb2 when mounted and sdb1 with the boot directory copied from the live usb stick. When I try and boot from the new hard disk menu option I still get "Cannot get disk parameters" for hd0-5.