# I recently made a usb full 20.04 OS boot disk but it isn't booting properly, how can I fix this?

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.04, usb, mount

I recently tried creating a full OS installation on a 16 GB flash drive I partitioned it so it would have have fat32 partition  with a mount point labeled **/fatpartition** which I dedicated 4gb and the remaining 12gb I partitioned to ext4 with the mount point **/**

It completely installed fine but when I goto load it I am greeted with an "error: invalid environment block, press any key terms continue" if I press any key it starts the Ubuntu loading screen but after loading nothing comes up but a frozen mouse cursor. I decided I would goto grub and see if I could fix from there but after the grub menu loading screen finishes I get a jargon screen which I will post below.

[Jargon I received after grub load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJYdl.jpg)

If anyone has any ideas let me know, for the meantime I will try reinstalling on a seperate usb drive.

**UPDATE**
I went to reload the drive to see if waiting at the mouse cursor might help this time after the bad environment error, it brought me straight to BusyBox command line showing an error

(Initramfs) [11.053906] ata3: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)

Comment: Are you trying to install to the disk you have booted from? For this you need to boot to RAM. I have been recommending flashing a USB drive using an Ubuntu image file: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi . If you prefer starting from scratch have a look at this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step

Comment: I installed from 1 usb to a seperate usb. I will try from scratch and use the method described in the page and see if I get any results.