# How to install Ubuntu in a file?

Tags: system-installation, chroot

Everything in Linux-based systems is a file. Everytime I install Ubuntu, I choose a root partition. Now, I want to create a root filesystem, but in a file, for example `~/ubuntu.img`. I've got another Linux distro (based on Ubuntu) as the main OS. Is there a way to install (s)ubiquity and select `~/ubuntu.img` as the root filesystem? As far as I know, the installer mounts the root filesystem at `/target` and uses `chroot`. Maybe I can mount my root filesystem there and install manually?

I want to do this because:

1. I don't want to install more than 1 OS and dual boot.
2. My main OS doesn't support some packages or has some dependency issues when I want to compile some projects.

If I'm able to install Ubuntu this way, I'll use `chroot` to install packages inside the root filesystem image.

Comment: Sure, just mount it wherever and run `debootstrap` on it. But I don't see the point - you could pretty much get the same result with Docker or LXC containers with less hassle.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the response, I'll try to mount it. I want to use `chroot` because I'm used to it... I also need to access USB devices from the chroot environment and I thought it's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to mount the image from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1300458/1027810). You can use [this link](https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-06-26.img.xz) to download it.

For some reason I wasn't able to read the image directly using tools like `parted`, `cfdisk` or `fdisk`. I had to flash the image into a 16GB (or more) USB drive, and then copy the root partition using `dd`, or the GNOME Disk utility.

So, I copied the root partition to `~/ubuntu.img` and set up the chroot environment:

```
cd # go to the directory where the root filesystem image is located
mkdir ubuntu
sudo mount -o loop ubuntu.img ubuntu
sudo mount -t proc /proc ./ubuntu/proc
sudo mount -t sysfs /sys ./ubuntu/sys
sudo mount -o bind /dev ./ubuntu/dev
sudo chroot ./ubuntu
```

I can even access USB devices from the chroot environment.

You've probably noticed that the internet connection works only partially - you can ping any server if you specify the IP address, but domains can't be resolved. This command should fix it:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

The downside of this method is that you always have to prepare the chroot environment if you need to access USB devices. But, that can be simplified by writing a shell script.

To clean up after you leave the chroot environment (and no processes are running there):

```
sudo umount ./ubuntu/{proc,sys,dev}
sudo umount ./ubuntu
```

I think there's a way to manually install Ubuntu on top of a base system. There are tools like `debootstrap`, but I didn't try that. Feel free to post another answer with that :)

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest is essentially the idea behind a virtual machine. Why not simply use VirtualBox and install Ubuntu as a VirtualBox VM?

Comment: That could work for Android ROM building, but 1. the USB devices don't work the same way there; 2. I'd get less performance in a VM

Comment: Less performance? Really? Did you measure that, or is that just an assumption?

Comment: `chroot` is different than a VM. In a VM, another Linux kernel gets loaded with the full OS. Using `chroot` will use the kernel from my main OS, and only execute binaries in the chroot environment. This way, I don't need any virtualization, which could slow down things.

Comment: Right, it will use the kernel from that other OS; and this is where the trouble starts. The glibc etc. in what would be the _guest_ system may or may not work with that kernel, depending on how different they are. Happy experimenting; but I think you will end up with something like docker or virtual machines anyway.

Comment: As I mentioned before, my main OS is based on Ubuntu (it's Pop!_OS) and I've manually installed one of the Ubuntu mainline kernels (https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) to get my touchpad working.

Comment: What could be different, is the `initrd`. But that'd happen only if Pop!_OS had its own kernel modules or something.