# Possible to install Ubuntu on Portable External Hard Drive?

Tags: boot, external-hdd, portable

Some background info:
I have to install Ubuntu for a school project, to use one of the programs on Linux for robotics. I currently have a desktop with an SSD that has Windows 10 on it and 1 TB HDD internally installed. I don't have enough space on the SSD and HDD to allocate for additional space. So I bought a Portable External Hardrive to install Ubuntu on it.

I have already made a flash drive with the Ubuntu ISO image file on it so I can boot it from my USB flash drive. I've already played around with my BIOS Settings and Boot Menu just to be sure that it can boot from the flash drive. I've also started the "Try Ubuntu" option so it's able to work. Everything works fine in that department.

My main question:
Would I be able to install Ubuntu on the Portable External Hard Drive, but still, keep my Windows Operating Systems intact? I would like to switch between both Ubuntu and Windows Freely and because this is Portable I would like to unplug the External Hard Drive when I'm not using Ubuntu if that's a possibility without damaging my internal hard drives, that way my default Operating System is Windows.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi. Yes, I just looked at that post, but the issue is that it was asked 6 years ago. Would the same procedure still apply? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Main thing is to double check where you are installing Ubuntu.  Quite a few of us did not pay attention and ended up installing over important data or Windows.  Make sure you know which drive is which.  Ubuntu can be installed on any type of drive, SD card, USB stick, or internal/external drives.

Comment: You weren't specific with any release details. I tested Lubuntu late last year and it was easy with one installer, difficult with another and I didn't test the 3rd installer choice (Lubuntu has three currently supported installers chosen by what ISO you download & use). You gave no release details, no specifics (desktop, server, appliance, etc), but Ubuntu Desktop has used the same installer for longer than 6 years, Ubuntu Server has 3 supported installers selected by ISO....  Yes it's possible with the right ISO choice

Comment: Makes a big difference if UEFI or BIOS and if you want to directly boot external drive from any other system?

Comment: For a quick and easy method of installinq to Portable External Hard Drive https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi

Comment: @user535733 There were no methods on that page for booting on UEFI computers, That would make the page obsolete. An EFI partition is not mentioned once.

Comment: If you want to create a Full install to USB from scratch see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step For any method it is safest to unplug your HDD first.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron since you have an excellent answer already written, would you consider adding that answer to the duplicate?

Comment: @user535733 Which excellent answer ;-) Done

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to find a computer running Linux, Windows, or Mac. Once you have done that just rename the .ISO to.IMG and go [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/) and download Raspberry Pi Imager on your computer of choice. Once you have done that, launch Raspberry Pi Imager and press the "Choose OS" button and scroll to the bottom of the list and select "Use custom" and choose the.IMG file that you renamed. Press the "Choose Storage" button and plug in the hard drive and select that hard drive's name. Once that's all done press the "Write" button. Wait a while, and now you have Ubuntu on a hard drive