# Remote Access from a Live USB 20.04

Tags: networking, network-manager

]
For a school project, I’m trying to be able to use Ubuntu on a flash drive, that I can plug into any/most computers, and remotely access a different computer. (At my house or my partners house.) I have set up a USB with a persistent version of 20.04 vs the trial version. When I run it

I wanted to try and create an adhoc network with Ubuntu. But when I start going through a tutorial on how to make one I realized that I was missing the network connections page
Example from tutorial:

[image]

What my screen shows:

[image]

https://adhocloopback.wordpress.com/2016/08/22/setting-up-an-ad-hoc-network-using-ubuntu-16-04/

So I tried to follow the manual steps to install network manager:

Followed steps to manually install network manger on USB
Sudo apt-get install network-manager
Sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
Try to run sudo start network-manager and get error
Sudo:start: command not found
Tried restarting network manager with
Sudo systemctl restart network-manager
Seems to work as it produces no error
Still cant start network manager

[image]

What am I missing, please help

Comment: Your question should specify whether you are using the Desktop image or the Server image. It's unclear how creating an ad-hoc network is related to remote access. Nether issue seems relevant to this question, since your only real problem here seem getting NetworkManager to work on a Live system. Your question should focus on the single, actual problem that you want help with.

Comment: For your project it may be better to use a full installation of Ubuntu in the USB. A persistent live USB is not the right tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

### Full Install vs Persistent install

Ubuntu can be installed to a USB in different ways. A Live install does not save between sessions. A Persistent install extracts the OS from a compressed file and saves data to an overlay file or partition each session, and a Full install installs the complete OS to the USB just like an install to internal disk.

**For your case see Full Install item 5)**

**Comparison between Persistent and Full install USB**

**Advantages of a persistent install:**

1. You can use the persistent pendrive to install Ubuntu to another computer.
2. A persistent install takes up less space on the pendrive.
3. You can reset the pendrive by overwriting the old casper-rw file with a new one.
4. The install to pendrive takes less time.
5. Slightly less wear on the drive.

**Advantages of a Full install:**

1. You can update and upgrade.
2. If you have problems or wish to modify, the solution is the same as with an internal install, (You can ask for help in the forums).
3. No ugly startup / install screen.
4. Better security, you can use full encryption
5. You can use proprietary drivers, many drivers need to start before the Persistent overlay opens therefore they do not work with a persistent install.
6. Swapfiles and partitions work and Hibernation can be enabled.
7. Many persistent installs are limited to a 4GB casper-rw and a 4GB home-rw persistence file, to get more persistence requires persistence partitions. Once casper-rw is full, the drive will not boot.
8. More efficient usage of disk space. Does not require reserved space for persistence.
9. Faster boot, **no automatic disk checking** or Try Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu screen.
10. You can run VBox and use virtual machines.
11. Generally faster boot than Live or Persistent USB's.
12. More stable, better for day to day use. I have run Ubuntu off a flash drive for 5 years making only LTS upgrades.

Note that once booted, both methods run at about the same speed. If the computer has lots of RAM Ubuntu should run mainly in RAM and there will not be a big difference between running off internal HDD and USB3 flash drive f.

**Full Install Method**

A quick and easy method to flash a Full install to USB can be found here: [Easy Full Install USB that Boots both BIOS and UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi)

A more traditional methods for creating a Full install USB from scratch can be found here: [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-st)

Comment: “For your project it may be better to use a full installation of Ubuntu in the USB. A persistent live USB is not the right tool for this.”
Is there a version of Ubuntu that: 
Can be installed on a USB, 
Is capable of being plugged into any/most computers
Contains all of the tools required to remotely access another computer?

Can a full install on the flash drive be used on any computer?
“since your only real problem here seem getting NetworkManager to work on a Live system.”
I guess I’m asking how to get a NetworkManager on a computer independent usb flash drive.

Comment: @Derick Try the first link in my answer, it is a real simple method to make a Full install that has all the tools of a desktop install.

Comment: So I installed a full USB ubuntu but I still cant see the network connections page. Is there a specific set of drivers I need to install to get to the network manager?

Comment: Have you tried Settings / Network or Sharing?