# How to install / configure ubuntu 20.04 LTS "Focal Fossa" directly?

Tags: boot, 20.04, shutdown, reboot

I have **Asus K50-IE** old laptop.
First time I installed it without any problems, and also I did all the updates, and it worked like a charm, even with the *Livepatch* option. Before I had *Windows 7 x64* os installed.

Then I reinstalled it once more (actually many more in different combinations), with the erase option, and put all the updates, and now **I can not shut down or reboot properly**. I repeated the process on a virtual machine, but there everything works just fine.

So far I tried

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and then replace
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`, which it almost works. It didn't power off completely.

I tried also replace with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash apm power_off"`

and finally I make it work with :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

with

```
sudo update-grub
```

which resolved the shut down, but it made the resolution smaller by half.
Then I resolved the resolution by running `ubuntu-drivers devices` and installed another driver for the video, and also append `video=hyperv_fb:1366×768` to Grub line, resulting in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=hyperv_fb:1366×768"`.

I even changed the time ammount to shut down, by entering somewhere in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and then change `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=5`.

But now I can not fix the **reboot** mode also. And I am sick and tired to look in each kernel settings. I am new to Ubuntu Linux.

Do you have an easier solution ? Some general that works every time ?

Before I didn't need to install drivers for ubuntu, so I guess I missing something.

Comment: Perhaps try installing from an **image file** as shown at this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi , The method was devised for external drives but works with internal drives also. Everything is already set up and ready to go.

Comment: "Then I reinstalled it once more..." Did you use the same installation medium, the same exact version of Ubuntu? (I mean also the third digit, e.g. 20.04.2). Subsequent point releases of ubuntu LTS use different linux kernels.