# Can't get Ubuntu to install

Tags: installation, live-cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is different about the Mac ISO image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image)

I have a brand new SSD in my laptop. I'm trying to boot Ubuntu from a CD I downloaded. I burned it on my Mac and I feel something is wrong with the CD. It is just a standard CD. Any idea what might be wrong with my install?

Comment: We need more details.  How did you burn the CD on your Mac?  What exactly happens when you try to boot off it?  It sounds like the CD isn't bootable for some reason.  Try booting your laptop off another bootable CD to try and single out the issue.

Comment: If you feel like the CD burning went wrong, please follow this guide http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-mac-osx : if you want to try a bootable USB stick please follow this guide http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: From what you're saying, it sounds like you might not be using [the Mac ISO image](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image).

Comment: Is the computer you are booting Ubuntu on the same Mac or another computer?

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided enough information so that we can help you. If you are having problem with your CD then you can try booting with your pen drive. For this just download Unetbootin which is available for free. And you can make Pen drive bootable instead of doing from cd.