# Difference between Ubuntu 64 bit for Macs and just Ubuntu 64 bit?

Tags: macbook, macbook-air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is different about the Mac ISO image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image)

What specifically is the difference between Ubuntu 64 bit for Macs and just Ubuntu 64 bit?

Edit: Is there any difference except UEFI and the boot procedure, like drivers, daemons, etc?

Comment: it probably just includes extra drivers specific to the mac

Answer (score 0):

The standard DVD supports both BIOS and UEFI booting, using a multi-catalog where the device is supposed to decide which should be booted.

Although Mac uses EFI (an earlier version of UEFI), it does not support the "multi-catalog", and as a result will not boot.

The Mac DVD uses just the one specific boot image for Mac.

[[Ref]](https://askubuntu.com/a/40480/24819)