# I'm trying to install ubuntu on my mac on a USB drive and dont know how to do the weird terminal thing

Tags: installation, usb, mac

I get messed up on step #3, how do I turn it into a .img file? Also would like help with rest of instructions pls

Comment: Can you please provide us with a link to the instructions you are following? We have no way of knowing what "step #3" is.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison It's almost certainly [this procedure](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx). So while an an edit clarifying this would be helpful, we don't need to close this.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you're having trouble with step 3 of [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx), which says you should run

> ```
> hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso
> ```

with appropriate substitutions for filenames. It also notes:

> OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file automatically.

You opened the Terminal (sometimes called Terminal.app, and located in the Utilities subfolder of the Applications folder), so you can enter commands. Suppose you downloaded the ISO image to your Downloads folder. Suppose further (for this example) that it is [the 64-bit Mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image/40480#40480) image of Ubuntu 12.10. That file is called `ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso`. (If it's not that, just get its name by looking at it in the Finder.)

You want to create `ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.dmg` from it, also in the Downloads folder.

`~` represents your home folder (which on OS X is `/Users/your-username`). The `/` character is the directory delimiter--that means that an expression of the form `X/Y` means *the folder called `Y`, which is a subfolder of the folder called `X`*.

So, you will run:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/Downloads/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac ~/Downloads/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso
```

Alternatively, you could use the `cd` command to go into the Downloads folder, and then the hdiutil command you'd run would be shorter:

```
cd ~/Downloads
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso
```

But being able to specify the full paths is especially helpful if you want to create the DMG image somewhere *other* than where you downloaded the ISO image. For example, if you downloaded the ISO image to your Downloads folder but you want to make the ISO image on your desktop:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/Desktop/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac ~/Downloads/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso
```

The newly created file will probably have a `.dmg` suffix--if it does not, you can give it one. (You can just rename it in the Finder.) You can also move it wherever you like, so it doesn't much matter *where* you create it, so long as you know where you're creating it.

#### Subsequent Steps

In case you have any trouble with the later steps too, here's a bit of explanation.

The `diskutil list` command lists disks that are attached, but the output is pretty technical. You won't necessarily know what names, like `disk1`, `disk2`, ..., correspond to what disks. So you run `diskutil list`, then plug in your USB flash drive, then run `diskutil list` again. Whatever item is *new* in the list is your USB flash drive.

To write the newly created `.dmg` image to it properly, it's necessary that it be *attached* but *unmounted*. To achieve this, unmount it:

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
```

Unless the USB flash drive's name in the list really *was* `disk2`, make sure to replace the `2` with whatever other number is correct!

To write the `.dmg` file to the USB flash drive, assuming the file is called `ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.dmg` and located in your Downloads folder, I recommend running:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dd if=ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.dmg of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
```

Just *make sure to replace the **`2`** with the correct number!* If you put in the wrong number, you can write the image to the wrong drive, and it would overwrite whatever files are already there, destroying them!

Writing the image to the flash drive with `dd` is step 8 in the procedure. If problems occur, please refer to the procedure itself, which explains them. (If you get this far, you may well be able to follow along; but if you do have any more difficulty, please feel free to ask!)

The procedure explains how to properly eject the USB flash drive (it's not mounted, so there's no icon on the desktop to drag to the trash/eject icon in the dock), and how to boot your computer from it.