# Is there way to check if users use Ubuntu Desktop amd64 or amd64+mac?

Tags: mac, iso, architecture

I believe `uname -a` on installation from both regular 64-bit and mac iso outputs the same info string. Is there way to tell apart their architectures?

Comment: No, these images are identical except for the way booting is done. See : http://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image  "CD images, which are exactly the same as the amd64 images except that they only support BIOS booting. "