# Can't Install Ubuntu 12.04.2 (desktop-amd64+mac) on Macbookpro 17" mid 2010

Tags: installation, boot, macbook-pro

I tried everything I could on my Macbook Pro Model: MacBookPro6, Intel Core i5, Boot ROM MBP61.0057.B0F SMC 1.57f18.

First I installed rEFit then I downloaded 'ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64+mac.iso', then converted it into `img` using `hdiutil` (with format UDRW), then I loaded it into the USB key using `dd`. After reboot... nothing.

Even if I press <kbd>C</kbd>, it doesn't load, it doesn't work even with rEFit, what's wrong? How can I get rid of OSX and have my Ubuntu running on this machine?

Comment: I formatted a USB Key with FAT and then used UNetBootIn with the latest ubuntu amd64+mac iso after all it gave this message  "The created USB device will not boot off a Mac. Insert it into a PC, and select the USB boot option in the BIOS boot menu."  After the reboot, it displaied :  "Error: Not Found from LocateDevicePath Error: Load Error while (re)opening our installation volume The firmware refused to boot from the selected volume. Note that external hard drives are not well-supported by Apple's firmware for legacy OS booting. * Hit any key to continue * "

Comment: Have you tried doing it via a CD? Also, before you try that, instead of rEFIt, hold/tap OPTION when your computer is booting up

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64+mac.iso` from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com. It's an unsupported release, whose benefits are not clearly communicated on the website ("This image is adjusted to work properly on Mac systems."). The filename suggests to be a special version for Mac, but the image doesn't has a EFI-compatible bootloader ([more info](https://askubuntu.com/a/40480/184555)), so the only way to boot this image on a Mac is from CD in BIOS-compatibility mode, not EFI mode. Therefore, booting this image from USB stick is not possible.

Try `ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` from http://releases.ubuntu.com instead. This image comes with an EFI-compatible bootloader and is bootable on Mac from CD or USB stick in EFI mode (Tested at this moment on MacBookPro5,5). For booting from USB simply copy the image to your USB stick the way you used to do before.

The tool rEFIt is unnecessary for single LiveCD or LiveUSB booting, but it's helpfull if you plan to have dual or triple boot options on your HDD.