# Advantages of using mac version of Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I was trying to use the mac alternate ISO to install ubuntu and it wasn't working out. I'm pretty sure I could fix, but I wanna know if it is worth it. What advantages does it offer for MBP 2010 15 inch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mac image is designed to be compatible with most macs. The reason being that mac's have specific hardware requirements and tweaks to get things running smoothly. The Apple firmware by default uses a GPT table to boot OSX in EFI or UEFI mode.

The most common reason to use the Mac iso however is that they are more likely to be seen by the firmware and thus be able to boot and install on your Apple machine without issue.

There is a very good explanation by Colin Watson [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image).