# Differences between installer disc images?

Tags: system-installation, mac

Looking at [the Quantal image download site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/) I notice two different amd64 images. What's the technical difference between `ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac` and `ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64`? Of course the first one is optimized to install on Apple machines, while the latter is more general.

But what is the difference that makes it more suitable for Macs?

Comment: See the accepted answer from the creator himself: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image