# Installing Ubuntu in a mac

Tags: system-installation, mac

I have installed Mavericks on my PC, now I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 but I'm not sure which file should I download: 64-bit or 64-bit mac.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Macs can't boot multi-catalog CD images, that's why there's a separate 64-bit Mac ISO.

If you're running on an actual Mac made by Apple (not a Hackintosh), grab the 64-bit Mac version.

Link:
[What is different about the Mac ISO image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image)

Comment: I have a late 2013 MacBook Pro and oddly enough I was able to boot the non-Mac 14.04 image. I was never able to do this with 12.04/13.10 which are the only ones I tried. I didn't install it so it's likely you might not get that far with it but it definitely boots on newer macbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Most Macs with Intel processors will work with either 64-bit or Mac images. If the 64-bit image doesn't work, try the Mac image.
In case of Macbook, you prefer to use 64-bit Mac.

Comment: I think that it's right in my experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Choose `64 bit Mac` in case standard `64 bit` won't work.