# Ubuntu does not boot via UEFI but does get boot via Legacy

Tags: uefi

I have a Ubuntu 13.10 CD.

When I try to boot using UEFI it won't boot (with or without Secure Boot), even if I change my boot priority.

It does boot when using Legacy BIOS mode.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or do you only get a black screen?

Comment: You could try using legacy bios mode. Even if the CD is BIOS booted, the installer should still do an EFI install if it detects an EFI system (eg. the [amd64+mac images do not  support EFI booting, but still install an EFI system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image)).

Comment: The installer installs in whatever boot mode was used to boot it. In other words, if you install in EFI mode, you get an EFI-mode installation; and if you install in BIOS mode, you get a BIOS-mode installation. Macs can switch boot modes relatively painlessly thanks to Boot Camp and third-party tools like rEFIt and rEFInd (the latter of which I maintain). You can also install [an EFI-mode boot loader](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) after the fact, on both PCs and Macs.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "won't boot." What are the precise symptoms you see? For instance, is there an error message? Do you see a GRUB screen appear with options to try or install Ubuntu? Do you see a disk activity light and then nothing, or nothing at all from the moment you select the medium? What type of medium are you using (USB flash drive, CD-R, or something else)? What brand and model computer are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the 64bit version? Have you turned off fast boot in bios?
Also, ubuntu is out with newer version [14.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)