# Which version of Ubuntu should I install under VirtualBox in OS X 10.9?

Tags: virtualbox, macosx

I'm planning to install Ubuntu in a VirtualBox virtual machine.  The host operating system is OS X 10.9 Mavericks running on a Mid-2012 MacBook Pro.

[The download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) instructs me to choose between the flavours "64-bit" and "64-bit Mac (AMD64)".

What is the difference between these two versions?

Which of these versions is appropriate for my planned installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer to a related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image) explains that the difference between these disk images is that the "64-bit Mac (AMD64)" version forces BIOS-mode (rather than UEFI) booting to avoid lack of support for multi-catalog CDs in the EFI boot mode of Mac machines.

So it sounds like I should be able to use either version, since the boot-time pseudo-firmware is entirely an aspect of the VM and not related to the underlying hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing in virtual box so any of the above version is fine.but i suggest 64-bit mac because you are using mavericks.have fun with ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox has very limited support for Mac guests, so I would suggest the AMD-64 version to prevent the possibility that some odd hardware emulation causes problems.