# 64 v amd64 distribution

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

This must have been asked many times, but for some reason it's not clear from about ten mins looking into it

why is there a separate 64bit and amd64?

does this mean 32 bit code won't run on the 64bit, but on;y on amd64?

or simply that intel and amd have diverged and 64 is intel optimized, amd is amd optimised?

Comment: There's a 32 bit, for computers which can handle only 32 bit programs, a 64 bit for newer processors, and an AMD64 for Mac computers.  Macs have a different set of hardware architecture than PCs

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose/157001#157001) is a brief introduction to 32-bit vs. 64-bit.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image and https://answers.launchpad.net/mactel-support/+question/162838

Answer (score 2):

`amd64` (or `x86-64`, commonly called 64-bit) is backwards compatible with `x86`, so software written for the latter can run on the former. The name comes from the fact that AMD came up with it, but Intel adopted it and software for `amd64` run just fine on Intel CPUs. Since `amd64` extends `x86`, `x86` can't run software written for `amd64`/`x86-64`.

Macbooks used to have CPUs of the PowerPC architecture, but they have long since shifted to the `amd64`/`x86-64` architecture. A separate image is offered for Macs not because of optimization, but because of booting issues caused by the UEFI implementation in Macs (see [What is different about the Mac ISO image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image)).

Ubuntu offers three options for the `x86` (commonly called 32-bit) and its successor architecture `amd64`/`x86-64` :

1. `x86` image
2. `amd64` image, UEFI/BIOS bootable.
3. `amd64` image, BIOS bootable (i.e., UEFI systems will boot them in the Legacy boot mode).