# Which ISO do I want for a VM on Mac OS X?

Tags: virtualbox, mac

Wanting to install 14.04 on a VM inside OS X.  There are two 64-bit versions of the ISO, the regular and the mac version.  I've looked at [What is different about the Mac ISO image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image), but that seems to be geared towards dual-booting, and not running in a VM.  Does it even matter?  (I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate but I can't find anything specific to VMs and I don't know enough about what UEFI is to know what it does, and if it's even important in a VM environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virtual box generates smt similar like bootcamp and let's you install whatever you want just install the regular 64 bit and i think you'd be good to go (I'm not sure but uefi is about bios, you don't have to do any settings for uefi in vm since is doesn't have to anything with bios

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any answer for you, it sounds like it really doesn't matter just pick one.  I was unaware that there were even two versions, I installed the one www.ubuntu.com sent me to download, I guess it was the default one.  I don't remember getting to pick.  So I probably installed the regular on my 2013 macbook pro.  It works great.