# Where can I download Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: 14.04, downloads

From a reliable source, no torrent sites. I want version 14.04.1 because 14.04.2 (trash version) doesn't work. Something is always not functioning. I don't know what they did to mess it up, but I have tested 14.04.1 and V2 on 3 computers and all of them work perfect with V1 unlike V2. Lets see if I can get some help for the first time in 2 years of using Linux asking a simple question. Instead of the super hard ones I never got help with. I googled it and the only site I found had mirrors with offline servers.

Comment: Instead of calling 14.04.2 a trash please explain what went wrong when you tried to install it or run?

Comment: For starters I can't change brightness, can't suspend, and I can't change graphics drivers I've looked it up and its seems to be a bug with pcs like mine, which they recommended installing 14.04.1. Problems I would rather just re-install 14.04.1 than deal with. I've already re installed V.1 on all my pcs but unfortunately I deleted it and I am going to make a tutorial on how to install Ubuntu for noobies but I want to give people a STABLE version that won't break on them or have them have to fix things. V.2 has not been stable for me on many pcs while I've NEVER had any problems with V1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old releases of Ubuntu get archived to [the old-releases server](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/). This often includes the older point releases of currently supported Ubuntu releases. You can get desktop images for 14.04.1 by clicking the link to that version, which brings you to [the *trusty* folder](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/).

Assuming you want one of the usual desktop ISO images (and not, for example, a server ISO image), you have 32-bit and 64-bit options, as with other releases:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1, 32-bit: [`ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso`](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso)
- Ubuntu 14.04.1, 64-bit: [`ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)

If you're looking for [the image built specially for compatibility with 64-bit Macs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image), you'll notice that hasn't been archived there (at least as of this writing). Instead it is on [the cdimages server](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/), which hosts many of the lesser-used ISO images:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1, for 64-bit Macs: [`ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac.iso`](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/trusty/release/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac.iso)

Since those are the official primary download locations for these images, they should be expected to remain available (and I have tested the three links posted here--they all work).

The [md5](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) hashes for Ubuntu 14.04.1, including all the above-linked images, remain available on the [14.04 section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes#A14.04_LTS) of the [UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) page.

---

If the problems you had with the 14.04.2 ISO image were with the installation, using the old 14.04.1 image is usually a good solution. However, if they happened from updating your 14.04 system, then installing from 14.04.1 *and not installing any updates* is at best only a short-term solution. This is because some of the updates users receive are provided to patch security vulnerabilities that have been discovered.

Therefore, you may consider proceeding in one of these ways:

- **Try an older kernel.** You can probably do this with your currently installed system. This fixes--or, in any case, works around--many hardware problems that start after an update. By default Ubuntu keeps some older kernels, when a kernel update is installed. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting to show the GRUB menu and (if needed) select *Advanced options*. Then you can select from the bootable kernels that are installed and try out older ones.
- After installing, allow security updates and not others, but do update it. (You can select "Important security updates" in the *Updates* tab in Software Sources, but uncheck "Recommended," "Pre-released," and "Unsupported" updates.) See if that prevents the problem. It might not, though.
- Try to figure out specifically which updates are causing the problem and disable only them. Some troubleshooting would be required for this.
- Try to find solutions to the problems you've had. You can post a new question about this (or multiple new questions about different problems, if the problems seem separate from one another).

Comment: Thank you so much. First question out of a dozens I've asked answered. Also to all the people thumbing me down. I love Linux but I am not going to pretend like its ok to release something like V2 (for ubuntu) that breaks stuff when V1 was ok. Each version/update should be more stable not less.

Comment: @user293645 I've expanded this with an additional section on working from an old point release without updates, as well as alternatives to doing so. Hopefully that will help you, but if not, potentially it may help others who come here with a similar problem to yours (or who are otherwise considering using the 14.04.1 image). Regarding the downvotes, it does seem rather silly since your question is on-topic, clear, and answerable (I upvoted it), but you might consider removing "Let's see .... a simple question" as it's meta and doesn't help describe the problem or context in which it occurs.