# How to convert multi-catalog Ubuntu ISO image to boot it on Macbook 2,1?

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu, iso, macbook

I was struggling for a long time with installing Linux on my Macbook 2,1 from mid 2007 with no luck. Finally I've managed to install Xubuntu i386 and have tried also Ubuntu 14.10 +mac ISO. Both installations succeed, but I'm using a pretty old hardware and finally I'd like to use Xubuntu 16.10 which installation ISO is created just like newest Ubuntu ISOs (what are the changes has been described [What is different about Mac ISO image?](https://askubuntu.com/a/40480/557757), as multi-catalog images and my old Macbook isn't able to boot them. And so I've got a question how to convert such multi-catalog ISO to "single-catalog", so old Mac can boot it?

Comment: I didn't find this question as 'unclear what you're asking'... There is a lot of chat in the question, but title 'How to convert multi-catalog Ubuntu ISO image to single-catalog +mac version' is completely unambiguous

Comment: I've changed the title of this question to better reflect what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in  [amd64+mac images no longer necessary](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1298894). I've tried this on a iMac, late 2006, core 2 duo, and it works.

You could conceivably use mkisofs with the correctly blend of options, but this method is fool-proof.

> If you are curious enough, here is a C program which i assume makes
>   the trusty-desktop-amd64.iso bootable on your 2,1.
>
> - Put both, a copy of the ISO and the C program as
>     make_single_eltorito.c   into the same directory.
> - Compile the C program:
>     cc -g -Wall -o make_single_eltorito make_single_eltorito.c
> - Run it without arguments (the ISO name is hardcoded in variable iso_name):
>     ./make_single_eltorito
> - Put the ISO onto DVD and try booting.

```
/*
 Removes all entries but the first one from the El Torito boot catalog of
   http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.iso

 Compile by:
   cc -g -Wall -o make_single_eltorito make_single_eltorito.c

 Run without arguments in the directory where the ISO image is stored.
*/

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char *iso_name = {"trusty-desktop-amd64.iso"};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fd, ret;
  unsigned char buf[2048 - 64];
  off_t lba;
  size_t buf_size = 2048 - 64;

  fd = open(iso_name, O_RDWR);
  if (fd == -1)
    goto err_ex;
  if (lseek(fd, (off_t) 32768 + 2048 + 71, SEEK_SET) == -1)
    goto err_ex;
  ret = read(fd, buf, 4);
  if (ret == -1)
    goto err_ex;
  if (ret < 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read 4 bytes from %s\n", iso_name);
    exit(1);
  }
  lba = buf[0] | (buf[1] << 8) | (buf[2] << 16) | (buf[3] << 24);
  if (lseek(fd, lba * 2048 + 64, SEEK_SET) == -1)
    goto err_ex;
  memset(buf, 0, buf_size);
  ret = write(fd, buf, buf_size);
  if (ret == -1)
    goto err_ex;
  if (ret < buf_size) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot write %d bytes to %s\n", (int) buf_size, iso_name);
    exit(1);
  }
  close(fd);
  printf("done\n");
  exit(0);
err_ex:;
  perror(iso_name);
  exit(1);
}
```