# Can I make a bootable USB flash drive for Mac from Windows

Tags: macbook

### The problem

MacBook hard drive crashed and is ruined. I need to work on a music assignment on a program only available for Mac OS X and Ubuntu, and will not be able to get a new hard drive for the Mac before the assignment is due. **I only have *non-administrator* access to Windows XP and 7 computers.**

### My question

Can I make a USB drive with Ubuntu on it so I can use my MacBook with this? Can I create this from a Windows computer? Please give detailed steps, if possible, for I am a noob when it comes to computers, and especially Linux.

I have an 8-Gb flash drive available.

Comment: I have an 8-Gb flash drive.

Comment: **Possible duplicate:** http://askubuntu.com/q/28495/43660

Comment: @Patrick + you could do that, but it has not the same results because of less size of installation like compared to the one you would prefer under Linux ( and by this way the graphical output under Linux is much more s-h-a-r-p-e-r ! ) +

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion about EFI booting and Ubuntu ISOs.

Disclaimer: I don't know much about Macs, because I never happened to own or support one of these machines. But I want to help anyway.

## Linux and Windows UEFI booting and Ubuntu Mac ISOs

Using Linux on Windows machines, my understanding is that to boot from external media via EFI you just copy the files from the ISO to a supported filesystem on the USB drive, which is usually FAT. ISOs that support UEFI booting contain a file called `/efi/boot/boot{arch}.efi`, where `{arch}` can be `x64` for AMD64, `ia32` for i386, `arm` or `a64` for ARM and so forth. On (older) Macs this may just be `/efi/boot/boot.efi`.

Okay, that's that. The strange thing is that the Mac ISOs don't contain such files and instead boot and install in legacy BIOS mode, which was fine in 2006 – when Apple introduced Boot Camp – but isn't since 2012 when the rest of the industry moved to UEFI.

The answers from [Chan-Ho Suh](https://askubuntu.com/a/130614/40581) and [Colin Watson](https://askubuntu.com/a/40480/40581) on similar questions don't seem to reflect the current state accurately.

## Fixing the problem with UEFI loaders for older Macs

I found a blog entry from [AstroFloyd dealing with a very similar problem](http://astrofloyd.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/boot-linux-from-usb-flash-drive-on-macbook/) while being aware of the above.

His solution is to put an [EFI loader that allows for loopback loading](http://www.mediafire.com/?dpgorsfdkf6nn2c) a UEFI-compatible ISO. Ideally you would just have to put two files on the FAT-formatted USB drive and that's it.

> For clarity, all that is now on your USB drive is (relative to the root directory of that drive):
>
> 1. /efi/boot/boot.iso
> 2. /efi/boot/boot.efi

His instructions are written using Linux tools and dealing with advanced details like setting the partition type, but I guess Windows and off-the-shelf USB drives already provide this configuration by default.

To be clear: Do *not* use the amd64+mac ISO, use the latest standard one.

Related:

- [Matthew Garrett's post about the multiboot catalog on Fedora 17](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/11285.html)
- U&L SE: [Booting Ubuntu from usb on a Mac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57964/49853)
- [Mac-Linux-USB-Loader](https://github.com/SevenBits/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/tree/working/EFI%20Loader) via [How do I boot linux from a EFI partition on a USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/q/372730/40581)

## More background information

Rod Smith – [who is also around here](https://askubuntu.com/users/93977/rod-smith) – has published a very detailed article about [EFI-Booting Ubuntu on a Mac](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/) on his site. He explains why installing Linux in BIOS mode on a Mac by using a hybrid MBR is at least to say a bad idea and covers a few scenarios of installing Ubuntu on a drive with an existing Mac OS X installation.

He is using his tool Refind, but as far as I know systemd-boot is also capable of booting OS X and working with Macs. It's probably a bit more difficult to configure.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1948):

> Intel-based Macs support starting from an external USB storage device's volume that:
>
> - Has been formatted with a GUID partition type
> - Contains an installation
>     of Mac OS X 10.4.5 or later, or Mac OS X 10.5 or later, which is
>     compatible with (or shipped with) the Mac that the USB device is
>     connected to. Note: You should not use a version of Mac OS X that is
>     earlier ("older") than the version your Mac shipped with.

So booting from a Live USB of Ubuntu with a Mac is not *officially* supported.

You may, however, try the steps described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) (no guarantees!), or alternatively, just boot from a Live CD.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, I have a Macbook 1.1 with the original OS.

Comment: and an intel core 2 duo processor. But the link is for working macbooks, which I don't have. I can't boot OS X.

Comment: Excellent point! :P Then I would suggest booting from a Live CD; it's much simpler.

Comment: I'll try that this weekend and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the instructions for booting off USB on that Ubuntu help page have never been known to work.  Ironically, the special workaround described for MacBook Air 3,2 doesn't usually work for that model, but works for others.

Comment: The information from the Apple site is about EFI while the Ubuntu Mac ISOs set up a legacy environment. I don't understand why everyone is still booting UEFI capable machines with legacy media and using `dd` to write the images where it could be much easier. :(

Answer (score 0):

There are many options that can help you to make a bootable USB drive from your Windows machine. My favorite one is Rufus (http://rufus.akeo.ie/). In order to create your bootable USB drive, perform the following steps:

- Download an Ubuntu ISO (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
- Download Rufus (http://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus-1.4.12.exe)
- Finally, insert your USB drive, run *rufus-1.4.12.exe*, select the ISO file and click on the *Start* button.

If you encounter any issues, you can refer to the FAQ (https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not having administrative access on the PC does take some of the more user-friendly programs out of the equation (e.g. Yumi).
However, after poking around [Pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) I stumbled across an option that might work: XBOOT. Pendrivelinux has a guide [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/xboot-multiboot-iso-usb-creator/), but the major steps are this:

1. Download the and unzip the application ([here](https://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/download))
2. Plug in USB Drive
3. Drag the [Ubuntu ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) into the program
4. Select "Create USB" and choose your drive

***edit:***
I just finished testing the program and it successfully created a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive when I ran it on my Windows box (Windows 8.1), *without* asking for administrative access.