# How do I boot linux from a EFI partition on a USB drive

Tags: installation, server, uefi, mac, grubrescue

I managed to create a USB drive image for booting with EFI using [Mac-Linux-USB-Loader](https://github.com/SevenBits/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader)([issue](https://github.com/SevenBits/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/issues/21)).

The directory structure is as shown here.

```
F:\>tree /f
Folder PATH listing for volume NEW VOLUME
Volume serial number is 9478-C771
F:.
└───efi
    └───boot
            bootX64.efi
            boot.iso
```

boot.iso is ~689MB and bootX64.efi is ~600KB.

While attempting to boot, I end up in the grub shell. I video recorded my screen and have some screen shots here.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How do I proceed booting? I care more to install linux on my mac mini (late 2012) than to fix this issue. I will be happy to boor boot manually and start the installer. I am installing `ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64+mac.iso`

Comment: Why don't you create a live media with the iso?  That seems to be what you are trying to recreate.  Use unetbootin (not sure on Mac though), or even just a block copy to the usb from the iso.

Comment: `dd` did not work unetbootbin does not get me an EFI boot. It seems to be creating an MBR. This is the only tool that has got me anywhere close to booting an EFI installer.

From my past experience, if I boot from MBR, the installation does not find `/sys/firmware/efi` and installs assuming an MBR. Then I have to go through a twisted process to convert the MBR ubuntu to an EFI ubuntu.

Comment: The 64 bit live media has both: the syslinux bootloader via the MBR, and /EFI/bootx64.efi (really shim.efi) with a copy of grubx64.efi too.  Not sure what happens with secure boot off, whether bootx64 still runs or not.

Comment: It does not seem to load it off EFI, but MBR Grub. :-(

Comment: Correct the mac ISOs don't seem to have EFI loaders. http://askubuntu.com/a/40480/40581

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me.

```
grub> kernel (hd1,gpt2)\vmlinuz-3.11.0-13-generic root=/dev/sdb3
grub> initd (hd1,gpt2)\initrd-3.11.0-13-generic
grub> boot
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make UDF region on your USB with 64 bit Ubuntu live iso, you can boot either EFI or BIOS mode. After Ubuntu installation on EFI mode, you have to replace grub-pc with grub-efi before rebooting.