# OSX Lion won't mount or read from Ubuntu 12.04 on a USB

Tags: installation, usb, macbook

I am unable to install ubuntu 12.04 onto a Macbook Pro 4,1 or even mount it on an iMac with a lion install after following guide on install page. Is this issue known or am I doing something wrong?

The USB shows a CD sized FAT partition on the 4GB USB.

Comment: **Duplicate:** http://askubuntu.com/q/28495/43660

Answer (score 1):

i have been unable to boot Ubuntu from USB drives on my MacBook. It is tricky because your USB drive has to be formated in a special way. I am not sure about the details, but there are some guides here. Installing REFIT might you with booting, but i would simply use a Live CD for booting.
There is a special version for Macs available here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ or simply use this direkt link: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso