# Creating a bootable USB Stick on Mac OS X

Tags: installation, usb, macosx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my Mac to boot from an Ubuntu USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key)

I followed the step by step instructions set forth here but none of my macs (all intel) will recognize the stick as bootable

diskutil list shows the following

/dev/disk7
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *4.0 GB     disk7
   1:                       0x17                         735.3 MB   disk7s1

thoughts or help or are the instructions just plain wrong

Comment: You might have already looked at this, but if not:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: **Duplicate** of http://askubuntu.com/q/28495/43660

Comment: Definitevely not a duplicate, the linked question is much broader, while this one address a specific technical error happening while following procedures (described in linked question!)

Answer (score 0):

Try reformatting the USB key to HFS+ in Disk Utility and making the (only) partition GUID, which is what the Mac expects of any bootable drive.