# How should USB stick in Lion for 12.04 be formatted initially?

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb, live-usb, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my Mac to boot from an Ubuntu USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key)

To create an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS USB stick in Mac OS X Lion, how should be the stick formatted initially?

Comment: Download Ubuntu: 32 bits PC / 64 bits PC / Intel Mac is the same mac or pc?

Comment: **Possible duplicate:** http://askubuntu.com/q/28495/43660  Not exactly a duplicate, but shows your question is the least of your problems.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, lsemac!

You don't need to format the USB before recording the USB, just make an USB image and burn the IMG using Disk Utility. The drive will be formatted automatically.

If you want to install Ubuntu in a USB drive:

1. Download Ubuntu: [32 bits PC](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&release=lts&bits=32) / [64 bits PC](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&release=lts&bits=64) / [Intel Mac](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso)
2. Follow the instructions at [the Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

As it seems too difficult, I'm going to make a Python script which can simplify the process :)