# System suggest for PowerMac G4

Tags: mac, cpu, powerpc, ppc, system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the current version of Ubuntu usable on a PPC mac?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147037/is-the-current-version-of-ubuntu-usable-on-a-ppc-mac)

- Processor: 400 MHZ (PPC 7400)
- Ram      : 768 MB PC133 (+1 GB swap on HDD)
- Graphics : 256 MB HIS ATI Radeon 9550 128bit
- HDD      : 80  GB 7200rpm Seagate ATA
- Monitor: 1680x1050 LCD

I want to use ubuntu but proccessor is too slow. Graphic card is good for unity 3D (I tested it on another computer). Ram's capacity is enough to ubuntu.

Which system you suggest me? Lubuntu 12.04 or Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: What do you plan to do with your computer? I used my power mac G3 as a server. (until the HDD crashed...)

Comment: It will be used only for surfing on web and download.

Answer (score 0):

Before suggesting a system to install, maybe you need to look at the information provided below.

> Apple changed its hardware architecture in the late 1990s, creating a
>   split in its product lines between "OldWorld" and "NewWorld" PowerPCs.
>   All G4s and later machines are NewWorld.<sup>1</sup>

For instructions covering installation of Ubuntu on Macs, see 
[PowerPC](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPC)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[PowerPC](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPC)</sup>

Comment: I read them and I have a question.Is the title "Radeon kernel configuration changed" on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCKnownIssues contains my card? Can I use my card with 3D accerlation?