# "dd: /dev/disk4: Permission denied" error when making LiveUSB on Mac OS X

Tags: system-installation, usb, macosx

I'm following the steps in [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) to install Ubuntu on a USB stick, and I keep getting the error:

```
dd: /dev/disk4: Permission denied
```

when I try to run step 8, even if I use `sudo` and enter my password.

I know this is probably a silly little mistake, but I'm not familiar enough with the terminal to figure it out on my own. Anyone out there who could help? (I'm using OSX, by the way.)

Answer (score 39):

One common cause for this is a "locked" SD card. Unfortunately it seems that the sensor in the MacBook Pro and Air can get stuck. It **can be fixed with a can of compressed air**.

[A lot of us ran into](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=5561&p=232800&hilit=mac%20osx%20blow#p232800) this trying to image SD cards for the Raspberry Pi. And with that device you have no option but to boot off of the SD.

This raises a fascinating fact. It seems that the lock switch is a [purely mechanical](https://www.google.com/search?q=sd%20card%20lock%20switch) "intent indicator" that must be sensed by the host device. This is analogous to the way the lock switch worked on 3.5" floppy drives, so it should be no shock to those of us old enough to have to punch a hole in our 5.25" floppies to make them writeable. (And cover the hole with tape to make them readonly!) However, because it is called *Secure Digital* and is solid state, you would expect the card to protect itself, not rely on the host.

Comment: really interesting! I had a sandisk microSD connected through a sandisk microSD adapter and I was getting `Permission denied`. I used a different adapter and it works fine. Also doing Raspberry Pi work.

Comment: @mtpain, Hmmm. Well, with microSD it's definitely a different issue because there is no write lock switch on it. I'm sure you have the ingenuity to devise a series of tests to see if you have a bad adapter or a just a fluke combination of devices that don't work well together.

Comment: You can also tape the lock switch into the unlocked position.

Comment: I can not believe this solution worked. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I was using an SD and it was in fact in the locked status

Comment: I can't begin to express my surprise that blowing on my MBP's card slot was the solution to this problem. I haven't had to do that since the N64 days!

Comment: @bloudermilk I KNOW RIGHT! Blows my mind even 5 years later.

Comment: There are SD card style adaptors for microSD cards, which even have the write lock switch on them. After reading this I just blew in the port and it then worked.

Comment: I had the same issue flashing a Raspberry Pi, I'm astounded that this was the solution.

Comment: same as @bloudermilk! blew my mind that the solution was blowing air in the card slot of my mbp :)

Comment: Late to the party - I just found this. Some sellotape helped me :-)

Answer (score 12):

I came across this once too. Use 'diskutil' to check the device your SD card appears as:

```
diskutil list
```

Then unmount it (Don't unmount using 'Finder', it wont work):

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk_4
```

Now use the 'dd' command to load your image:

```
sudo bash -c 'gzip -dc the_image_file.img.gz | dd of=/dev/disk_4'
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly: don't unmount using 'Finder', it wont work

Comment: Using `diskutil unmount /dev/disk3` instead of `sudo umount /dev/disk3` worked to solve the "Permission denied" for me.

Comment: If this disk is mounted, I get a different error "dd: /dev/rdisk3: Resource busy"

Answer (score 3):

Since it's silly that sudo (essentially 'root') can't access the device with dd it would seem that the error message "Permission denied" does not actually mean that root has a permissions problem.  iow it's a red herring.

Double check that the device is not still mounted - run the unmount command again as per step 7 and double check that it really *is* unmounted but still accessible as a device.

A common problem I've had with making USB boot devices under *linux* is an inconsistent partition table.  Delete the partition table completely and remake it, then create the new new partition as FAT and format it for good measure.  The errors I get under Linux don't make any more sense than this one, so I'm hoping that this is what your problem is.

I'll have a shot at removing the partition table under OSX.  Note that I am a linux user, so I'm relying on the fact that OSX is *similar*, and that the same thing seems to be found for OSX on a google search.

First we'll use dd to erase the partition table on the USB drive.  In a terminal type:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk4 bs=512 count=1
```

This should overwrite the first 512 bytes of the device, thus destroying the partition table.  Instructions I found [here](https://sixohthree.com/934/removing-all-partitions-in-mac-os-x) seem to suggest

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk4 bs=1 count=1024
```

for OSX however the difference is minor and I believe the end result should be the same.  As for any dd operation make sure you have the correct partition as there will be nothing left of the data on the device after you press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Next I believe you should use disk utility to to recreate the partition table, and a new partition, and format it FAT.  I'm a linux user, so I'm afraid I can't be more specific but I believe that the disk utility should complain that that there is no partition table and either make one for you, or prompt you to do so.

Comment: Hmm.. I confirmed that it's unmounted. I tried running the step 8 command again with it mounted and it gave me the same error, so it hasn't even managed to get far enough to care. I have no idea how to work with partition tables or where to find them. Maybe you would be able to explain?

Comment: Well I've had go, though I don't use OSX so I'm shooting blind here.  If this doesn't work you could try a different USB pendrive.

Answer (score 2):

Here was my solution:

Sudo wasn't asking for my password when I tried to use it.  I thought that was odd.

So, I su'd to root and did it from there.

```
sudo su
<enter password>
```

Then I ran the commands and they worked.

Answer (score 1):

### Use sudo in front of the dd command

```
sudo dd if=/Users/JPurcell/Downloads/Fedora-18-x86_64-Live-Desktop.iso of=/dev/disk2
```

**WARNING:** Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

that fixed the permission denied for me. it seems to be working now.

and I was root before hand. I also did the

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk4 bs=1 count=1024 before sudo dd if=/Users/JPurcell/Downloads/Fedora-18-x86_64-Live-Desktop.iso of=/dev/disk2
```

I did it right after without reformatting the usb drive. 
I dont know if its been successful but lights blinking on the drive and terminal is not giving me errors.

Comment: The only one that worked for me (I could not unmount it either)

Answer (score 1):

Potentially try ejecting the usb drive and reformatting first, then retry all the steps. diskutil list, unmount, then write the iso to the disk. I ran into similar issues where dd was giving permission denied errors and I reformatted my usb and everything worked correctly.

Comment: Reformatting the disk before running dd solve my problem. The reformatting must be done from Terminal with `diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 BOOT /dev/disk2`, because "Disk Utility" app didn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l /dev/disk2` gave me this result:

```
brw-r-----  1 root  operator    1,   5 Dec 17 10:27 /dev/disk2
```

I solved the problem by changing the owner of the file:

```
sudo chown <myUser>:<myGroup> /dev/disk2
```

Then I was able to dd the files to the USB stick.

Comment: When I do chown - still have 
```chown: /dev/disk2: Operation not permitted```

Answer (score 0):

From [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/28495/18612), a comment on the [highest-voted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/130614/18612) seems to suggest you aren't the only one having troubles with `dd`.

The same answer recommends using optical media (a.k.a. a LiveDVD) instead of a USB drive if you can, as that seems more reliable.

<sub>*Note: I am not and never was a Mac user, so I'm afraid I can't help out much more than this.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Well, I struggle a lot with this but finally succeed...

```
server:~ myusername$ sudo dd if=/Users/myusername/Desktop/ubuntu1304.img of=/dev/disk1s1 bs=1m
```

**WARNING:** Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to abort.

```
Password:******
```

DONE!

Points to check:
USB formated for FAT
usb disk should be unmounted.
usb disk => 2Gb
All this in iOSX Mavericks ver 10.9

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem because I was attempting to dd the wrong device. diskutil list showed /dev/disk0, /dev/disk1, and /dev/disk2 I was using /dev/disk2 should have been /dev/disk1

Answer (score 0):

For me, simply restarting the Macbook solved the problem.