# Install 12.10 on Macbook 6,1

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, macbook, bootcamp

I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 besides MacOSX 10.6 on my Macbook 6,1. I found some instructions like here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook/TripleBoot
But these are pretty old and I'm not sure whether they will still work and everything. So I'm asking for some up-to-date instructions or information about whether this will work and how to do this.

My guess would be:

1. partitioning using bootcamp
2. somehow install this rEFIt thing
3. install ubuntu via usb or cd

But I have NO idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Please note that this answer could be outdated. There is probably a more up-to-date solution to this.

I got it installed. At least the most information I got from here:
http://tech-devnet.blogspot.de/2012/05/running-ubuntu-1204-on-mac.html

What I did:

1. installing rEFIt, which is pretty easy. I had the problem that rEFIT didn't start without pressing [alt] while booting, but the solution is the manual install which is easy and described in the rEFIt documentation.
2. create a free partition using bootcamp (on snow leopard)
3. boot an ubuntu dvd. You can do that pressing [C] while booting.
4. install ubuntu.

Probably I wouldn't have had so much trouble when I skipped the bootcamp part and just let ubuntu split the thing automatically (it seems like ubuntu can do this, i didn't try).

But I have to warn people. On my macbook6.1, about 4 Years old, I can use macOS 4 hours and more, but ubuntu only 2 hours until the battery is empty. Even with using powertop, jupiter etc. Many power saving tutorials do not work anymore because they are too old.

To improve Battery life try things like proprietary GPU drivers, laptop-tools-mode and so on. Also there is a repository called mactel on launchpad, providing applesmc and macfanctld which will provide a better automatic fan control with good standard settings, easy to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Does my answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219886/impossible-to-boot-ubuntu-on-a-usb-stick-os-x-montain-lion/219998#219998) help you? I looked at the [Snow Leopard tech specs](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP575)
and the process I recommend in that question should work the same way for you.

Comment: Not really. Whether I install via DVD or USB stick isn't that important, I can do both. I'm more concerned about the whole rEFIt thing and installing Ubuntu without breaking something. I hoped someone had experience with this and could give me some tips, since most instructions are pretty old. I found a newer instruction article to 12.04 per accident which seems good, I think I'll try that when I have some time and report in a few days. This is it: http://tech-devnet.blogspot.de/2012/05/running-ubuntu-1204-on-mac.html