# Can't convert iso to img on mac

Tags: iso, macosx

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) and I got a `dmg` instead. This is what I entered:

```
cd Desktop
hdiutil convert ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso -format UDRW -o ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.img
```

Then it gave me a `dmg`. What should I do?

Comment: Can you point where did you get that instructions?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: That's fine, it's not openable. But it can be converted and booted from.

Answer (score 4):

From [that very same documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx):

> Note: OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file automatically.

It seems it's not a problem. Just continue to the next steps, and when prompted for the file name, be sure to provide the correct one, with the .dmg extension. That's all.

Comment: It still says 'no mountable file systems' when I click on the new file. Is this a problem? Should I just continue?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a Mac OS X user. The instructions don't say a thing about clicking on the file, so I'd continue without worrying.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command,

```
hdiutil convert -format Rdxx -o ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.img ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Use Rdxx instead of UDRW.

Answer (score 1):

Find the DMG file in finder and rename it to remove the trailing "dmg" extension.
(Finder will ask you if you're sure.  You are.)

Once you've done that, everything else will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

An `.iso` file and an `.img` file can normally be used [interchangeably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.img) with little or no effect. Just rename the file so that it includes a `.img` extension.

```
cp ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.img
```

If you get stuck, you can burn an image to [DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx), as well as a [thumb-drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

Comment: When I try to open it, it says 'no mountable file systems' I tried renaming it and it doesn't work. I tried entering the command you suggestion and it didn't do anything. I am just trying to make a usb out of it so I can try it out. If it is this frustrating just to download then I might just say f- it and stick with osx

Comment: I'd try the DVD route before USB.  See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key/) to see why.