# Is there any way to use ubuntu to convert an ISO to DMG?

Tags: boot, mac, iso

I have an intel Imac (early 2006).  I recently decided to install ubuntu on it as the sole OS as it was running 10.4.11 and was unable to meet my current needs.  The optical drive on it is broken,  so I downloaded the ubuntu iso,  converted it to a DMG and created a bootable flash drive.  Everything seemed to be going great.  I used gparted to wipe the hard drive and than began running the installer from the live enviro.   That's when things took a turn for the worst..  Half way through the installer crashed.  I attempted it a few more times,  but it eventually just froze solid.  I asked around what to do and was told to just reboot and try again.  Now it is not seeing the flash drive, and there is no OS to boot to,  so I'm just getting the ol' grey screen with a flashing question mark..

I bought a new 500gig external that I can format for a mac..  I'd like to try and install ubuntu on it and see if I can maybe boot the mac off it to try and fix and finish the install..

I mainly want to know how to convert an iso to a dmg using my other ubuntu machine,  but failing that,  I'm open to any suggestion.

Comment: What type of error are you getting? Like what does your screen look like?

Comment: see also [hdiutil on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/226439/hdiutil-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

You can just rename this [How to create an .img file from .iso on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388037/how-to-create-an-ubuntu-img-file-from-iso-on-ubuntu)

You will not have support for 10.04 however, you may want to install a lighter version (but newer) for older computer.

Comment: so I can essentially use the same commands as I would on the mac?

Comment: @MaxwellMeulendyk yeah `dd` is a unix based tool, and Mac has heavily modified Darwin (Unix). You can also use the disk utility as well if you want to do GUI

Comment: very nice.  Thank you very much.  All in all,  does what I'm planning seem like it should work,  or just a waste of time?  Also,  the mac had 10.4, I'm not using ubuntu 10.04.  just to clear that up

Comment: @MaxwellMeulendyk You will probably need to mess with the EFI (Macs don't boot like other computers) http://askubuntu.com/questions/16604/install-ubuntu-on-intel-mac is similar question, but going straight to the source is probably the best. So rEFInd and rEFIt would be the things to mess with your EFI. I am sure there are better answers than that. I just cannot find them right at this moment. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html I cannot remember if it is depreciated or not

Comment: I had refit installed on it.  that's how I got into the ubuntu live environment to begin with,  but now that the hard drive has been wiped, and however much of ubuntu managed to get installed on it there is nothing what so ever to boot to.  I'm not really sure how I'd be able to put refit or refind on it at this point..

Comment: @MaxwellMeulendyk Are you able to get into your live ubuntu?

Comment: not with the flash drive that I originally used..  It just stopped recognizing it..