# Having a lot of trouble converting a simple iso

Tags: system-installation

Im not new to computers. Ive worked at IBM for several years. I am trying to help a friend convert an ISO file to an IMG so he can install bootcamp on his (Mid) 2010 macbook pro. I have had Absolutely NO luck with any forms or Q&A. I have used The terminal and disk utility. I have done this before using a 16GB flash drive. But there is no option to do so on his computer. I have searched this website  and a large number of other websites back and front for litterally hours. EVERY LAST Q&A HAS DONE **NOTHING**. If someone can help that would be nice. Does mac really suck this bad? Our next step is to strap fireworks to the effing POS and use it for target practice.

Comment: Did you try using the `dd` command?

Comment: No just forget it. We lit it up with fireworks and shot it for fun. Lesson learned. Never buy apple products.

Comment: @NateDaniels And the sky.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/388321/373012) post.

The structure of ISO files and IMG files are the same... so all you would need to do is change the extension.

```
rename 's/\.iso(?=[^.iso]*$)/.img/g' *
```

Now, to create an img, you should use dd and save it into a file called img.

Read the post for more information.

Comment: I'm sorry. For whatever reason part of my question is missing. In short I'm trying to Burn the converted file to a flash drive.

Comment: try this: except select the img file instead of the iso http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: does that work?

Comment: No. We used it for target practice instead.