# Bootable Ubuntu USB Stick just not possible on Macbook

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, mac, macosx

In case someone else attempts this they should not try any of the following routes when attempting to make a bootable installation or live ubuntu CD. Basically, nothing works and Ubuntu should probably remove the option of installing or using from Macbooks from their site considering that many/most new macbooks wont even have DVD drives. In order, I've tried:

Without rEFIt installed all of the following failed:

- Convert iso to img, dd to USB stick (default recommendation on site)
- Same as above but partitioning with MBR first (shouldnt make a difference but you know, when stuff fails you get desperate)
- Same as above but partitioning with GUID first
- Use unetbootin on a MBR partitioned stick with original iso (unetbootin only works with MBR/MSDos)

With rEFIt installed all of the following failed:

- Convert iso to img, dd to USB stick (default recommendation on site)
- Same as above but partitioning with MBR first
- Same as above but partitioning with GUID first
- Use unetbootin on a MBR partitioned stick with original iso

Basically, there is simply no route. Or am I missing something?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/130614/20459

Comment: @yusf and everyone else: I'm not a Mac user, however the little research I have done tells me that answers like the one from Chan-Ho Suh misrepresent the actual issue. Fedora had bootable images, you can find details in Matthew Garrett's blog and I posted a FAQ with my findings [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/559007/40581). It also depends on the firmware of the Mac in question, newer Macs simply boot from a standard ESP. This question does not help bringing topic further, it should be removed.

Comment: I am in the same spot with an old Mac Mini.