# Problem with creating a bootable USB stick on OS X?

Tags: live-usb, macosx, dd

I have followed the guide from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx and then at step 8, which is "Execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m`", I get a problem, it says: "`dd: /Downloads/ubuntu.dmg: No such file or directory`". I have checked, it should be there.

Help needed, Thanks :)

Comment: I have tried using ubuntu.img, but it's the same "dd: /Downloads/ubuntu.img: No such file or directory"

Comment: You have to use the name of the image you downloaded, "ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.img" or what not. Check for the name of the file.

Comment: still dd: /Downloads/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.img: No such file or directory

Comment: You have to use the correct path and name of the file. Use your file browser to find it if it is not in /Downloads and identify the correct name

Comment: It worked, thx :D

Comment: Were you ultimately able to boot your mac via USB with this method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my Mac to boot from an Ubuntu USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key) and [Make an Ubuntu bootable USB drive for a PC using Mac?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454041/) This question is also off topic no-repro because the author hasn't visited this site for six years.

Answer (score 1):

`dd: /Downloads/ubuntu.dmg: No such file or directory` means there's a typo in your command.

Most probably, ubuntu.dmg is not in the Downloads folder at the root of the hard drive, but in the Downloads folder of your home folder. So the address would be `~/Downloads/ubuntu.dmg` (note the `~`).

To be sure to get it correct, just drag `ubuntu.dmg` from the Finder to the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using those directions, try using http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ . I have never used it on a Mac but it works on Windows and Linux.

Comment: I have tried that one, but I can't boot a non OSX usb-stick inside my mac.