# How to boot Ubuntu on Mac

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, 64-bit, mac

I tried many ways to boot Ubuntu on my Mac operating system. I do not have an internal CD drive, but when I tried to install it using the external CD drive (from Apple), the drive does not work. Admittedly, Apple made it clear that you can't do this.

I tried using many tools. I downloaded the AMD64 + Mac edition and copied it to my USB using UNetbootin. It said that it would not boot on Mac, but the instructions on another blog claimed that it has no problems as the iso will handle it. It also instructed to install rEFIt and it worked for him, but it doesn't boot for me. I even tried the terminal method of installing but this didn't work either.

What should I do to boot Ubuntu on my Mac?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get my Mac to boot from an Ubuntu USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key)

Comment: The Apple USB CD/DVD drive takes a lot of power to run and so may refuse to operate unless it gets told by the connected computer the required power is available.  As far as I know all Apple computers without an internal optical drive will supply sufficient power for this USB drive but I may be mistaken.  Use of a hub can interfere with the drive getting enough power so plug the drive directly into a port on the Mac.  I've seen this problem before but it may not be obvious to those that don't use this drive often.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I end up doing.  I couldn't boot from USB.  I downloaded the [Power-PC](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso) ISO from Ubuntu, for my G4 Mac, and this is what I did:

Macintosh-HD --> Applications --> Utilities --> Terminal

```
hdiutil burn <file_name>.iso
```

Placed the CD in the drive, and powered the machine down.  Then I held down the option key, and powered on the machine, clicked on CD, and then on right arrow.  Hope that this will help you.