# Installing on windows but downloading on Mac

Tags: system-installation, windows, hp, mac

Hypothetically speaking, would I be able to download Ubuntu desktop on a Mac and flash it and then plug into a windows laptop to install? Asking as my laptop has been wiped clean and my only option is to try this way, but wondering if there will be any tricky complications in doing so

Comment: No need to be hypothetical. That works just fine. Be sure to [verify the .iso file](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview) before putting it on the USB stick, and you'll be fine 

Comment: You can download an ISO on any device connected to the internet, and write to USB using any device that can do it, though instructions are available only for Ubuntu (*or any GNU/Linux actually*), macOS, or windows ... https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: @matigo anywhere I can send you a screenshot? Just ran the install and everything was fine until restart, have been having so many issues it’s crazy and not even more errors coming up

Comment: You don't "send a screenshot" but you can [edit] the question to add info or, better, ask a NEW question because whatever happened after installing has nothing to do with this hypothetical question which, by the way, is very poorly described. "Installing in Windows" typically mean WSL, something completely unrelated with what you actually asked. If the  "laptop has been wiped clean" then there's no Windows, totally nonsensical then to ask about "installing on Windows".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a bootable USB on a Mac to install Ubuntu on a PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364683/create-a-bootable-usb-on-a-mac-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-pc)