# dd: Operation not supported (on unmounted, but not ejected drive)

Tags: mount, usb-drive, dd, unmount

I have looked through the other questions here on AU, and none of them seem to help me deal with this particular problem, so I am starting a new question.

For some context, all I am trying to do is install the [Ubuntu Rescue Remix](http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/) image onto an external USB drive. I am currently running these commands on my iMac, according to the steps made available via the Ubuntu Rescue Remix instructions.

My problem is that even after I unmount [but not eject] the destination USB drive (assigned to /dev/disc4); I still get the `Operation not supported` error, which (I think) is the error someone gets when trying to run a `dd` operation on a mounted drive (or "Resource Busy" error).

So here is the command I run:

`sudo dd if=ubuntu-rescue.img of=/dev/disc4 bs=1m`

And here is the result I get:

`dd: /dev/disc4: Operation not supported`

The output I get from running `diskutil list`:

```
...
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.3 GB     disk4
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 8GBUSBFLASH             8.3 GB     disk4s1
```

So can anyone help me understand why I can't seem to run the dd command on /dev/disc4, even after it has been unmounted, yet not ejected?

Thanks!

**Update:** Someone cited [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key) as a potential solution to my question, so perhaps someone might find an answer there, but my question is unique, because it is asking in the context of `dd` operations, and the errors resulting from my `dd` operations --- the suggested answer doesn't talk about `dd` operations at all, so it can't serve as an answer to my problem.

Comment: shouldn't a usb drive usually show up as a `scsi` drive? Maybe you should try to use `/dev/sdX` instead of `/dev/disc4`?

Comment: @LittleByBlue Running the command as you suggested gives me this error: `dd: /dev/sdx4: Operation not supported`, similar to the error I am already getting.

Comment: replace `sdx` with `sdc` or `sdd` in your case it should be `/dev/sdd` and write it not to `sdd4` but to `sdd`

Comment: @LittleByBlue, same result: `Operation not supported`

Comment: I think you do not have somithing like `/dev/disc4` see `ls /dev|grep disc` there should be no results.

Comment: you are correct, there are no results after I run `ls /dev|grep disc`

Comment: look at `ls /dev|grep sd` then try to find the correct one show us the output.

Comment: `$ /dev|grep sd` --> `ptysd sdt ttysd`

Comment: Something went wrong. Are you using `sata` discs? or the old `IDE/pata`? there should be at least a entry for your usbstick. maybe you shuld (carefully) try to use `/dev/sdt`.

Comment: I am running these commands from an iMac. I downloaded the Ubuntu Rescue Remix and followed the instructions to make a bootable USB drive. Can you tell me what is the `/dev/sdt/` is it a hidden drive? a small partition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my Mac to boot from an Ubuntu USB key?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key)

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

There is (normally) no device called `/dev/discY`.

You will have to find your device using `ls /dev|grep sd`

this will return you someting like

```
$ ls /dev|grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sdb
sdb1
sdc
sdc1
```

then you mount the partition, of wich you think it could be your usb-stick

and see if it is the right device.

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt && ls /mnt
```

if it is it, unmount it

```
umount /mnt
```

and use

```
dd if=whatever.img of=/dev/sdc
```

to write the image to the device.

**Explanation**

Ubuntu seperates four kind of device types:

1. `scsi` drives

   these are today the most common. They are under the name `sdX`

   (sd = scsi drive) the the partitions are called `sdXY`.

   X is always a small letter starting from a and Y always an  integer starting from 1 .

   usb works with a kind of scsi protocoll, too.
2. parallel drives

   these are called `hdX` for hard drive.
3. removable devices (without usbs)

   these are called `srY` for optical drives, Y is here an integer starting from 0.

   `fdY` are floppys and so on..
4. Tapes

   are called nstY (guess what Y is) but you will most likely never face a tape.

The are all listed in the directory `/dev/` dev for device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the right location of your usb drive before you run `dd`. In my experience usually usb storage devices are located at `/dev/sd*`.

Check the output of `lsblk` to know where your usb drive is located.

Then use that location in dd. 
`of=/dev/sd*`

Answer (score 0):

The most hassle-free way to find out which device-name a certain disk/drive/unit has:

1. Mount the disk via the GUI (e.g. Nautilus)
2. Open a shell and type `lsblk`, press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The "MOUNTPOINT" column will have the label of the disk as in `/media/$USER/label` - assuming it has a label.
If there is no label, then unmount the disk and re-run `lsblk` - compare the lists.

As  you know the /dev/xxx device name running dd should work nicely with it unmounted and using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's **disk** not **disc**.

Unmount with `diskutil unmountDisk disk1` (or whatever disks shows you the command:`diskutil list`)

and then `sudo dd if="the iso file name" of=/dev/disk1`